# copy command in batch file is not getting executed when calling the batch file from another batch file, but is getting executed when i double click

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

i am trying to execute a command xcopy path1 path2 /Y /C and it is getting executed successfully when i tried from command line and also when i copied it to a batch file and double clicking on that batch file.

But it is not getting executed when i cal this batch file from another fail.

Could anyone please help here?

**Not working case:**

```
C:\abcd>cmd.exe /C "xcopy "C:\folder1\itsme.bat" "Y:\" /C /Y /Z" 
0 File(s) copied
```

**Working case:**

```
C:\abcd>cmd.exe /C "xcopy "C:\folder1\itsme.bat" "Y:\" /C /Y /Z"
C:\abcd\itsme.bat  
1 File(s) copied
```

Extra Info:

**Runme.bat:**

```
call C:\folder1\copy.bat
call C:\folder1\clean.bat
```

**copy.bat:**

```
@echo off
xcopy "C:\folder1\runrun.bat" "Z:\" /C /Y /Z /Q
xcopy "C:\folder1\runrun.bat" "Y:\" /C /Y /Z /Q
xcopy "C:\folder1\runrun.bat" "X:\" /C /Y /Z /Q
```

Here, If I double click on Runme.bat, copy.bat is getting executed and copying all the files.
    1 File(s) copied
    1 File(s) copied
    1 File(s) copied

But issue is, it is not copying anything when i try to run the same batch file from windows scheduler.
Output:
    0 File(s) copied
    0 File(s) copied
    0 File(s) copied

looks like issue is only with copy command in the second batch file, which will return output. But all the commands in the other batch file clean.bat (which i am calling from the first batch file) are getting executed without any issues.
second batch file has simple echo commands, so that is why it is working fine.

Comment: I don't see any differences between the 1st and the 2nd case.

Answer (score 3):

Use xcopy with 'START' command.
For example, c:>> START xcopy "C:\folder1\itsme.bat" Y:\ /C /Y /Z

As Mofi pointed out, you can remove 'CMD'

Answer (score 2):

The command **cmd** is for running a new instance of the command line interpreter and need to be used usually only for opening a command prompt window. Execute in a command prompt window `cmd /?` to get help about this command.

The command **cmd** does not need to be used usually if a command prompt window is opened already and a command is entered. A batch file is interpreted/processed by **cmd** and therefore it usually does not make sense to use **cmd** in a batch file.

So use only `xcopy "C:\folder1\itsme.bat" "Y:\" /C /Y /Z` in already opened command prompt window and in the batch file.

To process another batch file like `batch file 2` from within a batch file like `batch file 1` and continue processing of `batch file 1` after processing of `batch file 2` finished, use in `batch file 1` the command **call** for **calling** `batch file 2` like a subroutine.

Example for `batch file 1`:

```
@echo off
echo This is batch 1 calling now batch 2 and is waiting until it finished.
call "batch file 2.bat"
echo Batch 1 continues.
```

Example for `batch file 2`:

```
echo This is batch 2 running XCOPY.
xcopy "C:\folder1\itsme.bat" "Y:\" /C /Y /Z
echo XCOPY finished, batch 2 terminates.
```

Run `batch file 1` and you get the output:

```
This is batch 1 calling now batch 2 and is waiting until it finished.
This is batch 2 running XCOPY.
XCOPY finished, batch 2 terminates.
Batch 1 continues.
```

Remove command **call** in `batch file 1`, execute it again and look what you get now.

This time without **call** in `batch file 1` the processing of `batch file 1` **continues** on `batch file 2` without coming back to `batch file 1` on reaching end of `batch file 2` processing.

Answer (score 0):

From your extra information it may be that `x:` `y:` `z:` are network drives and task scheduler doesn't have network privileges under the system account.

Also, change the name of `copy.bat` because copy is a system command and using system command names will bite you one day, if not today.

Comment: So which account should I use here?