# Command to run a .bat file

Tags: windows, cmd, command, prompt

I'm trying to make my Visual Studio build script execute a .bat file that does something important.

Here is what I'm want to do right now:

```
cd "F:\- Big Packets -\kitterengine\Common\" Template.bat
```

But it doesn't work.

I have to do this to make it work:

```
cd "F:\- Big Packets -\kitterengine\Common\"
F:
Template.bat
```

But this is pretty difficult to add to the Visual Studio script.

How can I do this in one single line?

Comment: `"F:\- Big Packets -\kitterengine\Common\Template.bat"` maybe prefaced with `call` (see `call /?`). Or `Cd /d "F:\- Big Packets -\kitterengine\Common\" & Template.bat`. See my CMD cheat sheet - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40371443/what-do-all-commands-in-batch-mean-and-do

Comment: Not using Visual Studio, it is unclear if this questions and its answers apply to me. Either explain what the context of the "Visual Studio build script" is - or explicitly restrict the question by editing the title.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Can refer to here: https://ss64.com/nt/start.html

```
start "" /D F:\- Big Packets -\kitterengine\Common\ /W Template.bat
```

Answer (score 47):

`"F:\- Big Packets -\kitterengine\Common\Template.bat"` maybe prefaced with `call` (see `call /?`). Or `Cd /d "F:\- Big Packets -\kitterengine\Common\" & Template.bat`.

---

**CMD Cheat Sheet**

- Cmd.exe
- Getting Help
- Punctuation
- Naming Files
- Starting Programs
- Keys

**CMD.exe**

First thing to remember its a way of operating a computer. It's the way we did it before WIMP (Windows, Icons, Mouse, Popup menus) became common. It owes it roots to CPM, VMS, and Unix. It was used to start programs and copy and delete files. Also you could change the time and date.

For help on starting CMD type `cmd /?`. You must start it with either the `/k` or `/c` switch unless you just want to type in it.

**Getting Help**

For general help. Type `Help` in the command prompt. For each command listed type `help <command>` (eg `help dir`) or `<command> /?` (eg `dir /?`).

Some commands have sub commands. For example  `schtasks /create /?`.

The `NET` command's help is unusual. Typing `net use /?` is brief help. Type `net help use` for full help. The same applies at the root - `net /?` is also brief help, use `net help`.

References in Help to new behaviour are describing changes from CMD in OS/2 and Windows NT4 to the current CMD which is in Windows 2000 and later.

`WMIC` is a multipurpose command. Type `wmic /?`.

---

**Punctuation**

```
&    seperates commands on a line.

&&    executes this command only if previous command's errorlevel is 0.

||    (not used above) executes this command only if previous command's 
errorlevel is NOT 0

>    output to a file

>>    append output to a file

<    input from a file

2> Redirects command error output to the file specified. (0 is StdInput, 1 is StdOutput, and 2 is StdError)

2>&1 Redirects command error output to the same location as command output. 

|    output of one command into the input of another command

^    escapes any of the above, including itself, if needed to be passed 
to a program

"    parameters with spaces must be enclosed in quotes

+ used with copy to concatenate files. E.G. copy file1+file2 newfile

, used with copy to indicate missing parameters. This updates the files 
modified date. E.G. copy /b file1,,

%variablename% a inbuilt or user set environmental variable

!variablename! a user set environmental variable expanded at execution 
time, turned with SelLocal EnableDelayedExpansion command

%<number> (%1) the nth command line parameter passed to a batch file. %0 
is the batchfile's name.

%* (%*) the entire command line.

%CMDCMDLINE% - expands to the original command line that invoked the
Command Processor (from set /?).

%<a letter> or %%<a letter> (%A or %%A) the variable in a for loop. 
Single % sign at command prompt and double % sign in a batch file.

\\ (\\servername\sharename\folder\file.ext) access files and folders via UNC naming.

: (win.ini:streamname) accesses an alternative steam. Also separates drive from rest of path.

. (win.ini) the LAST dot in a file path separates the name from extension

. (dir .\*.txt) the current directory

.. (cd ..) the parent directory


\\?\ (\\?\c:\windows\win.ini) When a file path is prefixed with \\?\ filename checks are turned off.
```

**Naming Files**

```
< > : " / \ | Reserved characters. May not be used in filenames.



Reserved names. These refer to devices eg, 

copy filename con 

which copies a file to the console window.

CON, PRN, AUX, NUL, COM1, COM2, COM3, COM4, 

COM5, COM6, COM7, COM8, COM9, LPT1, LPT2, 

LPT3, LPT4, LPT5, LPT6, LPT7, LPT8, and LPT9

CONIN$, CONOUT$, CONERR$

--------------------------------

Maximum path length              260 characters
Maximum path length (\\?\)      32,767 characters (approx - some rare characters use 2 characters of storage)
Maximum filename length        255 characters
```

---

**Starting a Program**

See `start /?` and `call /?` for help on all three ways.

There are two types of Windows programs - console or non console (these are called GUI even if they don't have one). Console programs attach to the current console or Windows creates a new console. GUI programs have to explicitly create their own windows.

If a full path isn't given then Windows looks in

1. The directory from which the application loaded.
2. The current directory for the parent process.
3. Windows NT/2000/XP: The 32-bit Windows system directory. Use the
   GetSystemDirectory function to get the path of this directory. The
   name of this directory is System32.
4. Windows NT/2000/XP: The 16-bit Windows system directory. There is no
   function that obtains the path of this directory, but it is
   searched. The name of this directory is System.
5. The Windows directory. Use the GetWindowsDirectory function to get
   the path of this directory.
6. The directories that are listed in the PATH environment variable.

**Specify a program name**

This is the standard way to start a program.

```
c:\windows\notepad.exe
```

In a batch file the batch will wait for the program to exit. When
typed the command prompt does not wait for graphical
programs to exit.

If the program is a batch file control is transferred and the rest of the calling batch file is not executed.

**Use Start command**

`Start` starts programs in non standard ways.

```
start "" c:\windows\notepad.exe
```

`Start` starts a program and does not wait. Console programs start in a new window. Using the `/b` switch forces console programs into the same window, which negates the main purpose of Start.

Start uses the Windows graphical shell - same as typing in WinKey + R (Run dialog). Try

```
start shell:cache
```

Also program names registered under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths` can also be typed without specifying a full path.

Also note the first set of quotes, if any, MUST be the window title.

**Use Call command**

Call is used to start batch files and wait for them to exit and continue the current batch file.

**Other Filenames**

Typing a non program filename is the same as double clicking the file.

---

**Keys**

**Ctrl + C** exits a program without exiting the console window.

For other editing keys type `Doskey /?`.

- <kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>↓</kbd> recall commands
- <kbd>ESC</kbd> clears command line
- <kbd>F7</kbd> displays command history
- <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> clears command history
- <kbd>F8</kbd> searches command history
- <kbd>F9</kbd> selects a command by number
- <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> clears macro definitions

Also not listed

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd>or<kbd>→</kbd> Moves a word at a time
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd> Deletes the previous word
- <kbd>Home</kbd> Beginning of line
- <kbd>End</kbd> End of line
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>End</kbd> Deletes to end of line

Comment: Although this is useful information, the majority of it is not relevant to the question. The op did not ask how to use the command line or how to use a computer or batch in general which is the reason that I downvoted it: irrelevancy.

Comment: Although not relevant, this is highly useful for someone like me who's a n00b at CMD and anything command line based. StackOverflow should start a Wiki of some sorts where useful answers like this one can be easily searchable on Google :)

Answer (score 9):

There are many possibilities to solve this task.

### 1. RUN the batch file with full path

The easiest solution is **running** the batch file with full path.

```
"F:\- Big Packets -\kitterengine\Common\Template.bat"
```

Once end of batch file `Template.bat` is reached, there is no return to previous script in case of the command line above is within a *.bat or *.cmd file.

The current directory for the batch file `Template.bat` is the current directory of the current process. In case of `Template.bat` requires that the directory of this batch file is the current directory, the batch file `Template.bat` should contain after `@echo off` as second line the following command line:

```
cd /D "%~dp0"
```

Run in a command prompt window `cd /?` for getting displayed the help of this command explaining parameter `/D` ... change to specified directory also on a different drive.

Run in a command prompt window `call /?` for getting displayed the help of this command used also in 2., 4. and 5. solution and explaining also `%~dp0` ... drive and path of argument 0 which is the name of the batch file.

### 2. CALL the batch file with full path

Another solution is **calling** the batch file with full path.

```
call "F:\- Big Packets -\kitterengine\Common\Template.bat"
```

The difference to first solution is that after end of batch file `Template.bat` is reached the batch processing continues in batch script containing this command line.

For the current directory read above.

### 3. Change directory and RUN batch file with one command line

There are 3 operators for running multiple commands on one command line: `&`, `&&` and `||`.
For details see answer on [Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564)

I suggest for this task the `&&` operator.

```
cd /D "F:\- Big Packets -\kitterengine\Common" && Template.bat
```

As on first solution there is no return to current script if this is a *.bat or *.cmd file and changing the directory and continuation of batch processing on `Template.bat` is successful.

### 4. Change directory and CALL batch file with one command line

This command line changes the directory and on success **calls** the batch file.

```
cd /D "F:\- Big Packets -\kitterengine\Common" && call Template.bat
```

The difference to third solution is the return to current batch script on exiting processing of `Template.bat`.

### 5. Change directory and CALL batch file with keeping current environment with one command line

The four solutions above change the current directory and it is unknown what `Template.bat` does regarding

1. current directory
2. environment variables
3. command extensions state
4. delayed expansion state

In case of it is important to keep the environment of current *.bat or *.cmd script unmodified by whatever `Template.bat` changes on environment for itself, it is advisable to use `setlocal` and `endlocal`.

Run in a command prompt window `setlocal /?` and `endlocal /?` for getting displayed the help of these two commands. And read answer on [change directory command cd ..not working in batch file after npm install](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38676582/3074564) explaining more detailed what these two commands do.

```
setlocal & cd /D "F:\- Big Packets -\kitterengine\Common" & call Template.bat & endlocal
```

Now there is only `&` instead of `&&` used as it is important here that after `setlocal` is executed the command `endlocal` is finally also executed.

---

**ONE MORE NOTE**

If batch file `Template.bat` contains the command `exit` without parameter `/B` and this command is really executed, the command process is always exited independent on calling hierarchy. So make sure `Template.bat` contains `exit /B` or `goto :EOF` instead of just `exit` if there is `exit` used at all in this batch file.

Answer (score 6):

You can use Cmd command to run Batch file.

Here is my way =>

```
cmd /c ""Full_Path_Of_Batch_Here.cmd" "
```

More information => `cmd /?`

Comment: Thanks for this! I can know what is the error from command prompt because I wouldn't know that if I just double click to run the batch file :)

Answer (score -1):

Like Linux, to run the `myapp.exe`, you can use only one of these three methods.

### use system path

add `project` directory to your `systeme path`, then:

```
myapp.exe
```

or

```
myapp
```

### use full long path

```
\path\to\project\myapp.exe
```

### go to working directory

```
cd \path\to\project
.\myapp.exe
```

Comment: The question is "Command to run a .bat file", it is about BAT files not EXE!

Comment: When question and answer is more general, will touch a lot of people, not this one person.