# Remove all carriage return and line feed from file

Tags: powershell, batch-file, replace

Last week I have asked you guys to replace a string with newline character with .bat script. I have realized that my file has some carriage return and newline characters already, which I need to remove first and then do the replace.
 to replace '#@#@#' with linefeed I am using the line below.

```
(gc $Source) -replace "#@#@#", "`r`n"|set-content $Destination
```

So I tried to implement the same logic to replace \r and \n as well, however it did not work.

```
(gc $Source) -replace "`n", ""|set-content $Destination
```

my file looks like :

```
abc|d  ef|123#@#@#xyz|tuv|567#@#@#
```

and I need to make it look like

```
abc|def|123  xyz|tuv|567
```

like I said, replacing the row delimiter character with new line works, but I need to remove all cr and lf characters first before I do that.

For small files the script below works, but my file is >1.5GB and it throws OutofMemoryException error

```
param
(
  [string]$Source,
  [string]$Destination
)

echo $Source
echo $Destination

$Writer = New-Object IO.StreamWriter $Destination
$Writer.Write( [String]::Join("", $(Get-Content $Source)) )
$Writer.Close()
```

Comment: I believe it is not duplicate, since I am trying to remove all \r and \n. not the combination. Also I want to replace them with space only.

Comment: So you're trying to remove `\r` and `\n` but keep `\r\n`?

Comment: No, I am trying to remove all \r and \n . The file is not supposed to have linefeed character, since '#@#@#' is the end of line string. Having said that, is there anyway that I set my rowdelimiter as #@#@# and then read line by line in powershell to remove the \r, \n characters?

Comment: You confused me when you said you wanted to remove all \r and \n but not the combination. I don't know if you can use delimiters larger than a single character in PowerShell. My idea was going to be to convert the file to hexadecimal, remove any instances of `0d` and `0a`, and convert back to ASCII.

Comment: Considering it is big file, is it time-efficient to convert the file and remove unwanted characters? And what scripting would you recommend for that conversion?It has to be automated

Answer (score 0):

This is vbscript. Windows isn't consistent. Mostly it breaks on CR and removes LF (all inbuilt programming languages). But Edit controls (ie Notepad) break on LF and ignore CR (unless preceding a LF).

```
Set Inp = WScript.Stdin
Set Outp = Wscript.Stdout
Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
    Text = Inp.readall
    Text = Replace(Text, vbcr, "")
    Text = Replace(Text, vblf, "")
    Text = Replace(Text, "#@#@#", vblf)
    outp.write Text
Loop
```

This uses redirection of StdIn and StdOut.

Filtering the output of a command

```
YourProgram | Cscript //nologo script.vbs > OutputFile.txt
```

Filtering a file

```
Cscript //nologo script.vbs < InputFile.txt > OutputFile.txt
```

See my CMD Cheat Sheet about the Windows' command line [Command to run a .bat file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41030190/command-to-run-a-bat-file/41049135#41049135)

So this removes line ending in win.ini and prints to screen the now one line win.ini.

```
cscript //nologo "C:\Users\David Candy\Desktop\Replace.vbs" < C:\windows\win.ini
```

Comment: Thank you Noodles. When we say do until, does it loop line by line?

Comment: When we say do until, does it loop line by line? My file is huge and has only few carriage return line feed characters. How does this loop read the file? When we say Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream, what does it mean?

Comment: It once did but I changed it to a `readall` thus making the `Do ... Loop` unnecessary (it's goes through it once). Put a space between the `""` in the replace statements to replace with a space rather than just remove. So you could read line by line and `text = text & out.readline` and do the write outside the loop.

Comment: sorry, I haven't used any vb scripts before. Where does my source and tergat go here?

Comment: It's a command line thing not a vbscript thing. There are examples in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below function to remove the special characters. Put all of them in **$SpecChars** what ever you want to remove and call the function with the **Text-data** as a parameter.

```
Function Convert-ToFriendlyName
{param ($Text)
# Unwanted characters (includes spaces and '-') converted to a regex:
#Whatever characters you want to remove, put it here with comma separation.
$SpecChars =  '\', ' ','\\','-'
$remspecchars = [string]::join('|', ($SpecChars | % {[regex]::escape($_)}))
# Convert the text given to correct naming format (Uppercase)
$name = (Get-Culture).textinfo.totitlecase(“$Text”.tolower())
# Remove unwanted characters
$name = $name -replace $remspecchars, ""
$name
}
```

Hope it helps...!!!