# How to put a c++ variable data into system() function

Tags: c++, windows, codeblocks

How to put a c++ variable data into system() function?

Look at the code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  cout << "name the app u want to open";

  string app;

  cin >> app;

  system("start app"); // I know this will not work! But how to make it will?
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream)?

Comment: Reaserch: string concatenation, converting a `std::string` into a c-sting.

Comment: Bro, I am c++ beginner.

Comment: You have to concatenate strings. The first string is `start `. Your `app` variable is the second. There are many methods to do that - @Someprogrammerdude gave you one of them.

Comment: `system( app.c_str());` If you need to prepend e.g. the path, do this first, then it should work like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply concatenate the "start" prefix and `app` variable, and pass the result to `system()` as a c-style string, like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout<<"name the app u want to open";

    string app;
    cin>>app;

    const string cmd = "start " + app;

    system(cmd.c_str()); // <-- Use the .c_str() method to convert to a c-string.
    return 0;
}
```

You can use the same concatenation trick to add args and/or the file path to the command:

```
const string cmd = "start C:\\Windows\\System32\\" + app + " /?";

system(cmd.c_str());
```

The example `cmd` above will prepend the file path and "/?" command line argument.

For your example provided in the comments, you can do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Enter the profile name: ";

    string profile;
    cin >> profile;

    const string cmd = "netsh wlan connect name=\"" + profile + "\"";

    system(cmd.c_str());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: cin>>variable
 
how do for this : system("netsh wlan connect name="variable"");

Comment: How should i do if i variable is in the middle in system();

Comment: Got it bro! thanks alot! is there any way to contact if i need help?

Comment: Glad I could help. If you need further assistance just ask another question here on StackOverflow, there's lots of C++ experts on here to answer your questions :-)

Comment: Hope u would help , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41264572/how-to-store-cmd-memory-in-c-using-system-function-c

Answer (score 5):

Concatenate the two, then get the C string out of the `std::string` with `c_str()`:

```
system(("start " + app).c_str());
```

Comment: cin>>variable how do for this : system("netsh wlan connect name="variable"");

Comment: `system(("netsh wlan connect name=\"" + variable + "\"").c_str());` - not tested

Comment: How should i do if i variable is in the middle in system();