# How to bulk add text to beginning and ending of multiple files?

Tags: batch-file, bulk

I have subtitle files (.srt). I want to add some texts to beginning and ending of these files. They all are not in same folder. So it must effect to subfolders files,too. Is there a batch code or any other way to do this?

EDIT : This codes helped me to add text to beginning of files. How can I change it for adding to ending of files?

```
@echo off
for /r %%a in (*.srt) do (

echo 'text' > "%%a.tmp"
type "%%a" >> "%%a.tmp"
del "%%a"
move "%%a.tmp" "%%a"

)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding text to the begining of many existing .txt files using a batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41290680/adding-text-to-the-begining-of-many-existing-txt-files-using-a-batch-file)

Comment: Have you tried inserting `echo 'text' >> "%%a.tmp"` after the `type` command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are not familiar at all and have not attempted to understand the script at all...

`for /r`ecursive directory search after `*` (=all) `.srt`-files `do (`
`echo text >`(=into) `%%a`(=original filename as parameter of recursive loop)`.tmp`
`type >> %%a.tmp` (echo whole content of file to the end of `.tmp`-file)
`del`ete old file
`move .tmp`-file to old filename

So the line you are using to add text to the top is `echo 'text' > %%a.tmp` **before** typing the current content into it.

To add text after just move the same line **after** typing the current content. Additionally you will have to change `>` to `>>` as `>` means overwrite the file with said text and `>>` means append.

Comment: Thanks you very much for all these informations. Yes, I am not familiar :( Please forgive me, but I could not understand what I need to do/change to add text to end of the srt files.

Comment: Glad I could help!