# Check if input is a file or folder

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a command like this:

```
set /p txtfile=Write destination to the .txt file:
```

now i need to know if the file really exists so:

```
if exist %txtfile% echo file found.
```

it works, but if the user writes me C:\ it will display "file found" to.
I want to know is there a way to know a file extension using batch, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can identify it as a file using TYPE. However, it might not be the best way if it is a large file.

```
SET "DIR_ITEM=C:\Windows"

TYPE "%DIR_ITEM%" 1>NUL 2>&1
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
    ECHO "%DIR_ITEM%" is not a file
) ELSE (
    ECHO "%DIR_ITEM% is a file
)
```

Answer (score 3):

I assume you want to know whether the given item is an existing file but not a directory (note that directories can also have an extension). Use a trailing `\` to distinguish between file and directory:

```bat
if exist "file.ext" (
    if exist "file.ext\" (
        echo The given item is a directory.
    ) else (
        echo The given item is a file.
    )
) else (
    echo The given item does not exist.
)
```

Or in short:

```bat
if exist "file.ext" if not exist "file.ext\" echo This is a file but not a directory.
```

---

If you really want to check the name of a given item whether or not there is an extension, you could use a [`for`](http://ss64.com/nt/for2.html) loop:

```bat
for %%I in ("file.ext") do (
    if not "%%~xI"=="" (
        echo The given item has got the extension "%%~xI".
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
pushd C:\ && (Echo Is a folder & popd) || Echo Is a file or doesn't exist 2>nul
```

`&&` is same as `if not errorlevel 1` and `||` same as `if errorlevel 1`. `2>nul` hide error messages. Brackets make sure line is executed as I want by grouping commands. `Pushd` sets `errorlevel` to `1` if it can't change to the specified directory else `0`.

See my command cheat sheet here [Command to run a .bat file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41030190/command-to-run-a-bat-file/41049135#41049135)

Answer (score 0):

With `Dir ... /AD` shows only the directories. If it is not found, then an error is fired:

```dos
If Exist "%PathFile%" (
    Dir /B /AD "%PathFile%" 1>nul 2>nul && (
         Echo It is a directory.
    ) || (
        Echo It is a file.
    )
) else (
     Echo Folder or file does not exist.
)
```

> **Note:** If `%PathFile%` contains the keyword `*` of `?`, `Dir` could waste a lot of time. It is better to filter before this. I left it for your implementation.