# Unable to run batch commands using java class

Tags: java, batch-file

I have created a batch file with the following commands:

`@echo off
echo.>"Desktop:\testing\draft.txt"
@echo Writing text to draft.txt> Desktop:\testing\draft.txt`

This means that when I execute the batch file, I want a draft.txt file with some text in it to be created in the testing folder that I have created in my desktop. I want the batch file to be executed when I run my Java class. However, I get the following error:

> There is no program associated to perform the requested action. Please install a program or, if one is already installed, create an association in the Default Programs control panel.

Here is my Java class:

```
public class DraftBatchFile {
   public DraftBatchFile() {
    super();
   }

  /**Main Method
  * @param args
  */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Get Runtime object
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    try {
        //Pass string in this format to open Batch file
        runtime.exec("cmd /c start Desktop:\\DraftBatchFile.bat");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
  }
}
```

How do I get the batch file to execute the commands when I run the Java class? I am even unable to run the Java class. Why is that so? Do I have to add more code? Someone, please help me as I am new to this. Thank you so much.

Comment: Why do you use `Desktop:` instead of the absolute path the the file? What do you mean by `I am even unable to run the Java class` ? What is the issue?

Comment: The file is located at desktop. When i run the java class i get the error stating `There is no program associated to perform the requested action. Please install a program or, if one is already installed, create an association in the Default Programs control panel.` i got no idea why is that so

Comment: The problem is that your Windows does not know what to do with the `Desktop:` protocol since no application has been assigned as the protocol handler. But what happens when you run `cmd /c start %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\DraftBatchFile.bat`?

Comment: I have to run the java class to execute the DraftBatchFile.bat and when i run the java class, the draft.txt must be created in the testing folder. How do i go about doing that please do help me

Comment: @saw303 When i run `cmd /c start %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\DraftBatchFile.bat`, a command prompt opens and displays `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.`

Comment: I have double checked, the filename is DraftBatchFile.bat and it is in desktop

Comment: You should check the path of the file. In Windows Explorer right-click on the file and look for the Details-Pane.

Comment: Does it matter if i have two slashes? `cmd /c start %USERPROFILE%\\Desktop\\DraftBatchFile.bat` With one slash, i get the red line under the directory part (error)

Comment: @RalfRenz Hi, i checked and typed the exact same thing stated in the Details pane, `cmd /c start C:\\Users\\susha\\Desktop\\DraftBatchFile.bat` i still get `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.` error :(

Comment: OK. Maybe the error comes from inside your bat-file. Test this by filling the bat-file with a simple "echo hallo". - Does this work?

Comment: Sorry i am new to this. Do i have to just open cmd and type "echo hallo"? If yes, i get hallo

Comment: The three lines at the beginning of the thread are the content of the DraftBatchFile? Then you have to correct the paths in that file too.

Answer (score 2):

`Desktop:` means nothing.

```
    "%userprofile%\Desktop\Testing\Draft.txt"
```

Will do what you mean. (Note the quotes)

```
     Driveletter:\Folder\File.ext
```

So

```
     c:\windows\win.ini
```

See [Command to run a .bat file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41030190/command-to-run-a-bat-file/41049135#41049135) for additional info.