# Using For loop in CMD to get user input and use that to create .txt files

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I am trying to use for loop in CMD to 1) obtain user input as a number 2) use that number to create "n" number of .txt files starting from 1.txt and ending at n.txt.

I have this so far:

```
@echo off
set /p n="Enter a number:"
for  %%n%% in (1, 1, %%n%%) echo %%n%% > %%n%%.txt
```

I played around with the "%" since it is in a batch file.
If I just use this:

```
@echo off
set /p n="Enter a number:"
echo %n% was created
```

It will says "input" was created , if I add the "> %n%.txt" then it will create a file called n.txt with whatever the echo line says inside the .txt file and does not echo the result on the cmd screen.

Keep in mind that I am new to this, been playing with this particular challenge question for a few days and to no avail.

Any input is appreciated!

Comment: Open a command prompt, type `for /?` and look at the section for `for /L`. That should tell you everything you need to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set /p n="Enter a number:"
echo %n% was created
for  /l %%z in (1, 1, %n%) do echo %%z > %%z.txt
```

I guess typing randomly doesn't work so well.

Comment: Could you expand on this?

Comment: While this code-only answer may answer the question, please add an explanation of why it does so. This will help future users evaluate the answer for their situation.

Comment: There are 7 total misunderstandings in **one** line of code. Explaining requires a large batch file tutorial.

Comment: Thank you! This works,
I did not know that I should add another parameter %%z.
Much appreciated!

Comment: There's a little tutorial here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41030190/command-to-run-a-bat-file/41049135#41049135

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative use for for loop. Try this code. Simple use of batch command which will work for you.

```
set /p in="Enter a number:"
set /a n = 1
set /a count = %in% + 1

:loop
echo %n%
echo %n% > %n%.txt
set /a n = %n% + 1
IF %n% LSS %count% ( goto loop)
goto rest

:rest
```

Comment: Thank you!
This is excellent! However, we had to use for loop only for this particular case.