# Need to create a Batch file for which keeps the 6 latest files but need assistance with syntax

Tags: batch-file, command

I need to create a Batch file for keeping the 6 latest files in a directory. I have a prototype but need some help with the commands used.

```
 for /f "skip=6 eol=: delims=" %F in ('dir /b /o-d /a-d *.pdf') do @del "%F"
```

What do `/f`,`eol`, and `delims` do in this script snippet? Can anyone explain or point me to where I can find more information?

Comment: https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html That might be a start. It notes what all those things you're asking are for.

Comment: What you have posted is not, in any way, a batch file and if you find out what the `R` stands for in `R&d` you'll have the answer to your question!

Answer (score 0):

`/f` says you are parsing a file or output of a command. `Skip=6` says skip first 6 lines or the oldest 6 files from `Dir` command. `eol` is unnecessary. `Delims=<nothing>` says don't break the line on spaces.

All this is in `for /?`. Also see `dir /?`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41030190/command-to-run-a-bat-file/41049135#41049135 for a cheat sheet.

Comment: dir /b /o-d /a-d  means

Comment: He didn't ask that but I gave a for him to generically answer any question like this. `dir /?`.

Comment: when i use this command                                                                             for  /f "skip=6 eol=: delims=" %F in ('dir /b /o-d /a-d *.*') do @del "%F"               I am getting Could Not Find D:\FilesGenerator\MLPANO -  AWD No Policy Number_15_01_2017.pdf