# How to log the result of batch file running the icacls command in for loop in cmd?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd, icacls

I wrote a batch file to provide folder(D:\Test) access to list of user present in a txt(D:\users) file . Now I want a log file(D:\log) having names of who were provided access.

**Here is my code:**

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%A in (D:\users.txt) DO icacls "D:\Test" /grant %%A:(OI)(CI)F /T > D:\log.txt
```

**Output in log file:**

> Successfully processed 0 files; Failed processing 1 files

But I want those names who were given access.

**Note:-** D:\users text file contains correct user names and incorrect user names also.

Comment: `>>` appends to a file. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41030190/command-to-run-a-bat-file/41049135#41049135

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `ICACLS` command is correct I'd assume this would work:

```bat
For /F "UseBackQ Delims=" %%A In ("D:\users.txt"
) Do "D:\Test" /grant %%A:(OI)(CI)F /T>>"D:\log.txt"
```

and if you want the errors too I'd suggest:

```bat
For /F "UseBackQ Delims=" %%A In ("D:\users.txt"
) Do "D:\Test" /grant %%A:(OI)(CI)F /T>>"D:\log.txt" 2>>&1
```