# Opening cmd`s over and over that enter a single command in them with batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Basically i want to see if i can run a command in a cmd right when it opens but open tones of cmd's one after another. I`d like to learn how to do this myself but examples won't hurt. By the way, i do not have any experience whatsoever in batch aka notepad programming, only a little bit in javascript.

Comment: The command is [ip] -t -l [bytes]. In the future i`d like to have a cmd interface sort-of where you can put in the ip and bytes but for now the simpler the better.

Comment: `start /?`, `for /?` (`/L` switch) and for the future `set /?` (`/p` switch). (a command followed by the switch `/?` will show you it's helpfile)

Comment: No experience in batch but i`m gonna google about switches, thanks.

Comment: You'll find [SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/) very helpful.

Comment: Thanks, i will now attempt to learn more about cmd and batch on codeacademy.

Comment: tip: if you are "brand new" to programming, better learn Powershell, because batch is very old and not really a "language". It's a collection of independent tools with no common syntax glued together with some basic programming concepts like `goto`,`for` and `if`. Powershell is a designed language and much more powerful than batch. If you insist in learning batch - well, welcome to the land of headache. (though it's fun)

Comment: I know now what you meant by /?.

Comment: I don`t necesarely want to learn batch as much as i want to know how to use it properly if need be like right now when i wanna make a ddos cmd program with pings. Also i am already trying to learn Javascript. I haven`t started lessons in a while but atleast i know a lot about it. Also what is powershell used for?

Comment: [Powershell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShell) was invented to officially replace the "old, nasty" command line interface of `cmd` (aka `batch`). It's Part of Windows since Win7.

Comment: Umm okay.... soooo i made the ddos thing fully functional, gonna make a menu right after writing this and it works way too damn well. So well you basically have to restart your pc after using it but the victim is gonna feel the effects for a looong time until they restart their pc.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41030190/command-to-run-a-bat-file/41049135#41049135 and in a command prompt type `help` then for each command on the list `<command> /?` (eg `dir /?`).