# What does copy %1 "somefilepathhere" do?

Tags: batch-file

What does `copy %1 "Some\Filepath\Here"` do in a **.bat** file?

I understand usually the `copy` command has two parameters a *source* and a *destination*. I don't understand in this specific case tho what is happening with the %1?

Comment: See CMD Cheat Sheet http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41030190/command-to-run-a-bat-file/41049135#41049135

Comment: Type `call /?` into a command prompt window to find out what `%1` means; refer also to this: [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The %1 represents a command line parameter that is consumed by the batch file. If the name of your batch file is CopyMe.bat, then:

```
CopyMe SomeFileName.exe
```

would copy SomeFileName.exe to "Some\Filepath\Here".

Comment: Thank you ! Will mark this as answer when it allows me to.