# Open a random file from folder with Batch

Tags: image, batch-file, command-line

I'm an artist who is learning programming and I wanted to create a batch file that will select a random picture file from my references folder. The goal being to get a random picture to work on and study. I've looked around and the replies I see are hard to understand and are often linked with other features and functions I don't need. Simply put, how do I make a batch file that opens a random picture file from a folder (and subfolders)? Do I need to index every picture and then have a selector from that or can I just use %random% to open it?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you don't parse/index them all, you can't really have randomisation! Create some code using one of the answers you've seen, and if you have an issue with it, update your question to include it and you'll have an actual on topic question.

Comment: The basics are: 1) Determine how many files are in the folder structure. 2) Use that number with the Set command to get the MOD of the random number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the basic batch file structure you'll need:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "SrcDir=C:\Users\Jiosen\references"
Set "ExtLst=*.jpeg *.png *.tiff"
Set "i=0"
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Where /R "%SrcDir%" %ExtLst%') Do (Set /A i+=1
    Call Set "$[%%i%%]=%%A")
Set /A #=(%Random%%%i)+1
Call Start "" "%%$[%#%]%%"
```

You may need to adjust lines `2` and `3` as necessary, *(but do not remove or add any doublequotes)*.

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell is more efficient in selecting files in a tree and getting a random file so why not use it from the batch.

Taking [Compo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51489833/6811411)s batch as a template:

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\07\24\SO_51487674.cmd
@Echo Off
PushD "C:\Users\Jiosen\references"
Set "ExtLst=*.jpg,*.jpeg,*.png,*.tiff"

For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('
powershell -Nop -C "(Get-ChildItem * -R -File -Incl %ExtLst%|Get-Random).FullName"
') Do Start "" "%%A"
```

[Get-ChildItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-3.0) parameters `-File`,?`-Include` and [Get-Random](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-random?view=powershell-3.0) require at least PowerShell Version 3.0

According to the table in [this link](https://4sysops.com/wiki/differences-between-powershell-versions/) you need to upgrade Window 7 PowerShell v2 to at least V3, Windows 8 or higher should run the script without problem.
But I'd recommend to upgrade to 5.1 and possibly [install PowerShell 6.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/setup/installing-powershell-core-on-windows?view=powershell-6) (core) in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

```
@SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
rem @CD C:\newfolder
@set count=0
@For /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir C:\users\*.* /ad /s /b') Do (
@    set /a count=!count!+1
@rem     If !Count! gtr 1 echo Num of folders
)

@Set /a num=%random% %% %Count% + 1 
Echo %num% / %count%

For /f "skip=%num% delims=" %%A in ('dir C:\users\*.* /ad /s /b') Do (
Echo this is nth random folder
Echo Copy "%~dpnx0" "%%A"
rem Exit /b
)
pause
```

`%Random%` gives us a random number from 0 to 32K. `@Set /a num=%random% %% %Count% + 1` uses modulo division (ie the remainder from a division) of 32K divided by how many will give us a random number in the range 0 to `count`. Then add 1 to make it 1 to `count +1` (the number of folders). Then `skip=%num%` skips the first how ever many folders, reads the next, then exits the loop.

This is limited to 32K folders. See `Dir /?` for how to list files and files in subfolders. Every command above plus `/?` for help. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41030190/command-to-run-a-bat-file/41049135#41049135 for a CMD cheat sheet.

Comment: They asked for files. Not folders.

Comment: QUOTE **See Dir /? for how to list files and files in subfolders**

Comment: If you were a car salesman and the customer kept asking to see red cars and you kept showing them blue....... You essentially chose to keep showing them blue. Does your code answer the question as described? No.