# Image was unexpected at this time

Tags: windows, batch-file

So I'm working on [NBIS](https://www.nist.gov/services-resources/software/nist-biometric-image-software-nbis). I was trying to use `mindtct`. It works when I use it for an individual image but when I was trying to run it for a dataset I get this error,

> image was unexpected at this time

I've checked online and it says that it needs double % for it to work. I tried that and it still gives me the same errors. The directories are all correct. I'm using Windows 10

```
@echo off
Rem set the path of the photo directory
Set dirP= C:\Biometric\photos
Rem set the path for the mindtct
Set dirM= "C:\Rel_5.0.0\mindtct\bin\"mindtct.exe
Set image="*.png"
for %%A in image
do(
START dirM dirP C:\Biometric\Data
)
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41030190/command-to-run-a-bat-file/41049135#41049135 on how to use variables.

Comment: What did you check online? Apparently a syntax for a different scripting language because I cannot find any examples of using the FOR command like that in a batch file. Open up a cmd prompt and type the command name followed by a /? to get help for any console command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several flaws in your code:

- To expand a variable you've to enclose it in `%` signs (or `!` with DelayedExpansion)
- see syntax of `for /?` or view http://ss64.com/nt/for.html
- the start command uses the first argument in double quotes as the window title

---

```
@echo off
Rem set the path of the photo directory
Set "dirP=C:\Biometric\photos"
Rem set the path for the mindtct
Set "dirM=C:\Rel_5.0.0\mindtct\bin\mindtct.exe"
Set "image=*.png"
for %%A in (%image%) do START "" "%dirM%" "%dirP%" C:\Biometric\Data
```