# "access is denied" on cmd - NUL > filename.txt, though file creates

Tags: cmd, command-prompt

I am a little curious as to why, when I run the cmd `NUL > file` to create a file with Command Prompt (win 10) I am given "access is denied", though the file is still created?

I've tried both running as admin and not.

Could someone help me stop this error from appearing?

Comment: My guess is because you can't _read_ from the `NUL` device. If you want to create an empty file you could use `echo.>file` (all characters are important!)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yep! You're right. I'm very new to the command line, so I'm not too sure which commands to use for what. Thank you very much! I am assuming using `NUL >` won't hurt or damage a file, though?

Comment: `nul` is a file. Conceptually it exists in every directory. It swallows anything written to it. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41030190/command-to-run-a-bat-file/41049135#41049135. For background see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031022-00/?p=42073 and https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/adioltean/2005/02/25/tricks-around-the-copy-command/

Comment: cheers for the links @CatCat, really appreciate it! Thanks guys!

Comment: @Joe since you said, you're new to `cmd`: you should bookmark [SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/) then as a reference. (Btw: your file gets created, because the redirection is done before parsing the command before - even `yxz>file.txt` will generate an empty file - plus an error message, complaining about `xyz`not being a valid command)

Comment: Thank you, @CatCat. That ref looks incredibly helpful, I'll be hanging onto it for dear life, LOL. Cheers, @Stephan!

Comment: `type nul > filename` -make empty file without warning

Answer (score 0):

penknife deserves credit for this, but for some reason left it as a comment:

`type nul > filename` -make empty file without warning