# Old school "Commodore 64" BASIC - Peek/Poke commands; is there an equivalent in BATCH form?

Tags: batch-file, basic

I'm an 'Old Timer' that learned to program on a Commodore 64 with a cassette drive (not a disk drive) for storing data.  Oh the joy!

I am wondering if there is an equivalent way to perform Peek and Poke commands in a .bat file.  Is it even possible anymore to check a specific address the way it worked in BASIC language?

Can a batch file locate the address of something like whether or not the 'y' key has been pressed and can it also set the value of that address to indicate that key was pressed?

It used to be something like `PEEK(64324)` would return the value of that location. Likewise; `POKE(64324)` would set the value at that location.

I could run a loop that basically waited for a keyboard input and if it recieved the correect trigger at that address it would perform a command.  e.g.

```
For x = 1 to 1000
If PEEK(64324) = 1 then exit
Next x
```

So when the 'y' key was pressed, the loop would exit or goto the next command.  Can BATCH check a specific address for it's current state and if so, is there any repository or listing somewhere that tells what address is what for things like colors and keys on the keyboard?

Comment: Times have changed :). I remember those commands, but directly peeking or poking memory is so dangerous. Each process these days gets a virtual address space, that is mapped by the OS to physical addresses (not necessarily contiguous, but in blocks in different memory regions). Even for virtual address space, it is not possible to directly peek/poke it. My advice: research the programming language you will use (eg some form of BASIC), research the available functionality, and use the functionality to achieve your objectives.

Comment: I have no way of confirming this, but if you're on a 32-bit OS, you might (and I stress, _MIGHT_) be able to use `debug` to access memory. I don't know of any native way on 64-bit operating systems since `debug` is a 16-bit program.

Comment: The concepts are completely different. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41030190/command-to-run-a-bat-file/41049135#41049135 for an intro to Batch. NB: Windows has the following languages available (plus some Unix ones in  latest versions) VBScript, JScript, VB.NET, C#, and JavaScript. Batch is not a language but a way to operate a computer from a command line. It batches user commands.

Comment: You really want not to _peek_ memory locations, but to know _if a key was pressed_. There are several methods to do that in a Batch file, like [the XCopy trick](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5519&p=33741#p33741).  **PS:** I invite you to read [Batch file DOS systems programming via Peek.com](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6342) for a description about the "old school" peek concept translated into ("old" 32-bits Windows) Batch files! **`;)`**

Comment: @Aacini - Thanks for the link to the Peek.com files.  There are some very interesting concepts that I'm eager to play with.  Yes, of course, I tried executing it on my 64 bit system :P It's no fun if you can't break something.  I will have to dig out one of my 32's and do some more testing.  I think there is a lot I can learn from your examples.  Thanks for directing me there.

Comment: By the way, @Aacini, I would consider it an answer to my question if you wanted to post it as such.  As I stated, I couldn't test it on my system, but reading through the processes it does appear to at least perform a similar replication to the old PEEK command.

Comment: Batch files are primarily used for file management grouping command-line commands and not really used for general purpose programming. And Peeking/Poking is not something you do on today's computers. If you're looking to do some coding like in c64 BASIC, but in more modern environments, check out something like Xojo. http://www.xojo.com

Answer (score 2):

In MSDOS you can use the `DEBUG` tool to get a dump of memory:

`SHOWBIOS.BAT`

```
ECHO:d FE00:0000 0040 >debug.txt  
ECHO:q >>debug.txt  
DEBUG < debug.txt > debug.out
```

You can run the memory dump thru a script

```
-d FE00:0000 0040
FE00:0000 41 77 61 72 64 20 53 6F-66 74 77 61 72 65 49 42  Award SoftwareIB
FE00:0010 4D 20 43 4F 4D 50 41 54-49 42 4C 45 20 34 38 36  M COMPATIBLE 486
FE00:0020 20 42 49 4F 53 20 43 4F-50 59 52 49 47 48 54 20   BIOS COPYRIGHT
FE00:0030 41 77 61 72 64 20 53 6F-66 74 77 61 72 65 20 49  Award Software I
-q
```

Comment: I'm afraid I can't use the MSDOS `DEBUG` command on my 64bit processor without creating a virtual environment 32bit emulator.  I may, one day, set it up so I can try it though.  It appears `DEBUG` has a few methods to read, as well as, change memory values similar to `PEEK & POKE`.

Answer (score 0):

Times have changed, indeed, but in fact you could perhaps still do PEEKs and POKEs with the good old Motorola 68k family... because they like the 6502 used memory-mapped I/O.

I could be wrong, but I think computers today largely have abandoned memory-mapped I/O.  Instead they'll do something like the Intel 8x86 family.  It's been awhile since I took 8086 assembly, though.

Comment: The real purpose of those `peek` and `poke` commands wasn't to read or write to/from Memory (although that's exactly what they did), but rather reading/changing "properties" (like the color of text and background) - things, more modern languages have proper commands for. Commodore BASIC was very - well - basic (although I have to admit, with the help of those `p...` commands you could do very astonishing things). That worked because those "properties" were stored at specific memory addresses - modern computers don't use such a concept.

Comment: Stephan, that's a great observation.

Comment: Actually, I am currently using PEEKs to read high RAM... LOL!... so yes, memory-mapped I/O is an important feature of the 6502, but PEEK is still useful for reading data in hard-to-get-at places!

Comment: Memory mapped I/O and (not) being able to reach those addresses from user programs because of virtual memory/address space per process, so the operating system can enforce what a user program has access to, are two orthogonal concepts. The IBM PC/x86 design uses both, memory mapped I/O and a separate address space for I/O and it is possible to use memory mapped I/O with PEEK/POKE from DOS, but later processor models and operating systems didn't make the memory mapped I/O addresses available to user programs. But they did *not* abandon memory mapped I/O.