# Task Scheduler Runs Batch File - Batch File Only Works Partially?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, task, scheduler

My batch file is very simple. It starts a program, and echos "I ran" into a .txt file to prove that it ran for testing purposes. The settings for my Task Scheduler task are below:

```
General: 
- Run whether user is logged in or not.
- Run with highest privileges
- Configure for Windows 7, Windows Server 2008 R2

Trigger: 
-At startup, 15 min delay

Action:
- Start a Program
- Program/Script: STARTRDM.BAT
- Add arguments (optional): blank
- Start in (optional): C:\Scripts\

Conditions: None

Settings: 
- Allow task to be run on demand
- Stop the task if it runs longer than 1 hour
- If the running task does not end when requested, force it to stop
- If the task is already running, , do not start a new instance.

STARTRDM.BAT
>>log.txt echo I RAN
start C:\"Program Files (x86)"\Devolutions\"Remote Desktop Manager"\RemoteDesktopManager64.exe`
```

If I double click the batch file, it starts the program as expected and also writes to the .txt file. If I run the batch file through the Task Scheduler, the .txt is appended to as expected but the program is not started. This is driving me crazy!

Comment: not sure, if it solves your problem, but you really should quote the whole thing instead of just parts of it: `start  "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Devolutions\Remote Desktop Manager\RemoteDesktopManager64.exe"`. The `""` is because `start` takes the first quoted parameter as a window title (give it any value or `""` for "empty")

Comment: Why wouldn't you just have Task Scheduler run the executable directly?

Comment: `Start` starts programs in unusual ways. Why are YOU using `start`?. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41030190/command-to-run-a-bat-file/41049135#41049135

Comment: Thank's Stephan, but I've already tried that particular syntax.

Comment: Squashman, I did try that first actually but it wasn't working. I already had a task on other computer which runs a bat file just like this so I though it would be and easy solution.

Comment: CatCat, I just tried the bat file without start. It still works when double clicked, but only prints to file when run from the Task Scheduler

Comment: `Run whether user is logged in or not` runs the task without access to a desktop/screen/video. I guess `RemoteDesktopManager64` is a GUI program?

Comment: Hey Stephan, I couldn't get it to run with that setting on or off when logged in and forcing a run. I did figure out why and posted my findings below. It sounds like the fact that it is a gui application is going to be a potential problem though. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured it out so I thought I'd post the solution.

The station I was working on is set up as a Kiosk. The Kiosk account is what is usually logged in on this system. I was using a separate Admin account to author the tasks in Task Scheduler because Kiosk didn't have the necessary permissions. By default the field, "When running this task, use the following user account:" gets set to whichever account you are running Task Scheduler as. When I switched this field to the Kiosk user, it fixed my problem.