# Combine file with the same name from multiple folders into a single file using cmd

Tags: cmd

I would like to combine a file with the same name from multiple folders into a single file using windows cmd.

I have a file named `crudeoilm-f1.csv` in multiple folders (like `20160101`, `20160102`, e.t.c).

I would to concatenate this `crudeoilm-f1.csv` file into a single file.

Comment: What about repeated headers in the summary .`csv` file?

Answer (score 0):

```
For /f "delims=" %A in ('Dir /b /a /s "%userprofile%\*.csv"') do type "%A" >> "%userprofile%\Desktop\File.txt"
```

See `for /?`, `type /?`, `dir /?`, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41030190/command-to-run-a-bat-file/41049135#41049135.