# How to make a customized Batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, windows-7, windows-7-x64

When I restart my laptop (windows 7 64 Bits), I usually need to enter the following CMD commands to restore my Desktop icons, from Black squares to normal icons.

```
cd /d %userprofile%\appdata/local
del iconcache.db /a
exit
```

(I open CMD, and enter the above commands one by one)

I need your help in writing a Batch file that executes the above commands in the mentioned order.

Comment: You simply copy the code section in this question and paste it into a text file with either a .cmd or .bat extension. Totally unclear what exactly you feel you need help with.

Comment: A slash and a backslash? Although that will usually work, please use the correct `\ ` as folder delimiter: `cd /d %userprofile%\appdata\local`. Your code can be shortened to `del /a "%userprofile%\appdata\local\iconcache.db" (as IInspectable said, just put it into a textfile, name it with an extension of `.bat` and put it into your autostart (startup) folder.

Comment: That is the wrong way to fix this problem. See for example [How to Rebuild a Broken Icon Cache in Windows 10](https://www.howtogeek.com/232779/how-to-rebuild-a-broken-icon-cache-in-windows-10/). Also there is the predefined environment variable `LOCALAPPDATA` holding path to local application data folder of current user account. So `del "%LOCALAPPDATA%\iconcache.db" /a` is enough to delete this file, see [Windows Environment Variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Windows).

Answer (score 1):

**Delete The Thumbnail and Icon Caches**

These files may contain thumbnails or icons of long ago deleted files. The files will be recreated as needed.

Start - All Programs - Accessories - Right click Command Prompt and choose Run As Administrator. Type (or copy and paste by right clicking in the Command Prompt window and choosing Paste). The desktop and Start menu will briefly disappear.

To see size

```
dir "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\*.db" "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer\*.db" /a
```

then to delete

```
taskkill /im explorer.exe /f
attrib -r -s -h "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\*.db"
attrib -r -s -h "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer\*.db"
del "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\*.db" 
del "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer\*.db"
explorer
```

to check the new size

```
dir "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\*.db" "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer\*.db" /a
```

You put the same commands in a batch file. That is what batch means. A batch of command lines.

See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41030190/command-to-run-a-bat-file/41049135#41049135

See me full answer on cleaning drives here https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/profile/82459e77-cfe8-4587-a43a-f49f3302bc79