# How can I parse the top line of output of a previous command as input to another command?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

In bash I would use awk and xargs for this, but I'm not sure how to do it on the windows command line.

Basically I am trying to kill the process listening on port 3000. I am currently doing it like this:

```
netstat -ano | findstr:3000
taskkill /PID <process id found from previous command> /F
```

Is there a way to automatically parse the previous command to chain these in one line so I don't have to keep manually typing the latest PID? Or if anyone knows a better way, that's appreciated too.

Comment: `For /f` parses command output. `|` passess all output from one program into another. `For /f "tokens=4" %A in ('netstat -ano ^| Findstr /c:1900') do echo %A`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41030190/command-to-run-a-bat-file/41049135#41049135

Comment: It doesn't hurt to terminate a program multiple times. But by taking advantage of normal variable expansion - `(For /f "tokens=4" %A in ('netstat -ano ^| Findstr /c:1900') do @set myvar=%A) & Echo %MyVar%`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use a `for` loop to do this:

```bat
for /f "tokens=5" %A in ('netstat -ano ^| findstr /c:3000 ^| findstr /c:LISTENING') do taskkill /PID %A /F
```