# Windows batch: combining start and FOR /f "tokens=1" with | escape coded symbols

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, for-loop, find

I am trying to execute this command from standard windows batch file.

```
start /B for /f "tokens=1" %%a in ('Query SESSION ^| find /i "rdp"') do (echo yes |reset session %%a)
```

and it throws an error:

> "| was unexpected at this time."

I just found that it fails because `start` in the beginning.
What's wrong with it?

Comment: Why are you trying to run `start` on a `for` loop?

Comment: Don't use the `START` command.  There is absolutely no need for it at all.  Also the opening parentheses needs to be on the same line of the `FOR` command to extend it to multiple lines.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41030190/command-to-run-a-bat-file/41049135#41049135 *This is the standard way to start a program.

    `c:\windows\notepad.exe`

In a batch file the batch will wait for the program to exit. When
typed the command prompt does not wait for graphical
programs to exit.

If the program is a batch file control is transferred and the rest of the calling batch file is not executed.*

Comment: I see no legitimate reason here to execute a `for` loop by `start`, but if you just want to know the reason why it fails, here it is: 1) `start` passes the whole command to a new instance of cmd, so you have to escape any special characters (here `^ and |` needs to escaped by another `^`) and put the whole statement in one line.  2) Don't pass any internal command directly to `start` as it will invoke cmd by `/K` switch which keeps the cmd instance alive. So you should do like this `start cmd /c for ...`

Comment: 3) `start /b` causes the console to be shared and accessed by the parent and child process simultaneously, so they can mess with each other input and output. Try this on a new fresh console for demonstration of that messiness `start /b ping -t 4.2.2.4 & ping -t 8.8.8.8` so in general do not use `start /b` unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: @squashman./// Use start /b is a special resources in bat files, the advice need be use it, don’t not to use, because start some task in background can be result in some that the code will decide what instruction will be running based in then action, I`ve use it in some many bats, and not see a good point to not uso it, but, if would you like share the good technical appointment to do not use it, I will be grateful for earning from you!

Comment: > "you have to escape any special characters (here ^ and | needs to escaped by another ^" -- can you please be more specific, please show a working format?

Comment: > "start /b causes the console to be shared and accessed by the parent and child process simultaneously, so they can mess with each other" -- tried start /min, nothing changes.

Comment: I need start command in order to initiate parallel CMD thread from the batch, and without opening a new shell box. I.e. a few commands should execute concurrently, without waiting for completion. The opening parentheses are indeed in the same line - it is the stackoverflow formatting.

Comment: Try: `start "" /b cmd /s /c "for /f "tokens=1" %%a in ('Query SESSION ^| find /i "rdp"') do (echo yes|reset session %%a)"`. The outer double quotes will be stripped from the `/c` command line string.

Comment: Try `start "" /B ...`, although I see no reason to use `start` at all...

Comment: @aschipfl A reason could be that `QUERY SESSION` or `reset session` takes a lot of time, meanwhile you can do some other, independent actions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a batch file it's a bad idea to try to build a valid one line solution with `start`, it's very tricky to escape/quote a complex expression.

But it's quiet easy to use `start` and jump to a label in the same batch file.

```
@echo off
REM *** Thread redirector
for /F "tokens=3 delims=:" %%F in ("%~0") do goto %%F

REM *** Start a new thread in this batch file at the label :myThread
start "" /b cmd /c "%~d0\:myThread:\..\%~pnx0"

echo Main
for /L %%n in (1 1 10) DO (
    echo MainThread doing some stuff %%n
    ping localhost -n 2 > nul
)
exit /b

:myThread
for /f "tokens=1" %%a in ('Query SESSION ^| find /i "rdp"') do (
    echo myThread: Resetting session %%a
    echo yes | reset session %%a
)
exit /b
```

Comment: Ah, good idea. I just don't like "goto"s, so didn't consider it. But it looks like the only way.