# Get all files with a specific extension

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to get a file with a specific extension from a directory. To do that I am using the following batch file code:

```
for %%f in (.\*.ext) do (
     echo %%f
)
```

This works fine, unless I have a file with `.extsomething` extension.
I tried adding the `$` wildcard to get only the exact matching, but it doesn't show any results with it.

```
for %%f in (.\*.ext$) do (
     echo %%f
)
```

Since the `*` wildcard is accepted, why the `$` is not considered?
How can I get only the files with the exact extension?

Comment: The $ is more of a regular expression option.  You would need to pipe the output of the DIR command to FINDSTR to have some limited regular expression capability.

Comment: The short filename of the file matches your pattern. It will only use the first three letters of an extension in a short name. Filename.ext incl wildcards are matched against the short and long versions.

Comment: @catcat It is hard for me to follow what you are trying to tell me

Comment: @GarryWhite I turned it into a longer answer. This was your actual question *Since the * wildcard is accepted, why the $ is not considered?*. The answer is to that - `$` is not a wildcard.

Comment: @catcat You are right, thanks for the explanation, I also updated my question to my real request.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just add an `if` statement:

```
@echo off
for %%f in (*.ext) do (
    if "%%~xf"==".ext" echo %%f
)
```

Comment: It doesn't return any results :/

Comment: @GarryWhite do you have files with `.ext` in the dir?

Comment: My bad, I forgot to replace the `ext` with the actual extension :) I'll accept this answer since it is the closest to my initial code style

Comment: For the first approach: use `if /I "%%~xf"==".ext"` to make it case-insensitive. For the second approach: `findstr /v ".ext?"` should actually read `findstr /v "\.ext$"` (`\.` to match a literal `.`, `$` to anchor the match to the end of the string)...

Comment: @aschipfl actually, that would get rid of the .ext part and keep .extens, but anyway, that part of the answer is now no longer relevant so removed it, seeing as OP focused on the 1st portion of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Where` command:

```bat
@For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Where .:*.ext 2^>Nul') Do @Echo %%A
```

[Edit /]

According to the comment from aschipfl, you could use the more robust method of first emptying the content of PATHEXT:

```bat
@For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('(Set PATHEXT^=^) ^& %__AppDir__%where.exe .:*.ext 2^>NUL') Do @Echo %%A
```

Comment: You'd need to (temporarily) delete variable `PATHEXT` in order not to get files like `*.ext.exe`, `*.ext.com`, etc....

Comment: @aschipfl, I'll take your word for it, because I don't have a PC to check it against at this time, I would never touch that variable, _even temporarily_, and only a fool would create files named with `.???` as part of its name!

Comment: You think? I may be a fool, but for decades I have commonly used `filename.ext`, `filename.ext.bak`, `filename.ext.orig`, `filename.ext.new`, etc (mostly on Linux, but you could do that on DOS & Windows since DOS dropped the 8.3 name restrictions). imo, only a fool would name files any differently. You do NOT want your backup copy of an executable to have a `.exe` extension.

Comment: Almost four years... it had to happen. `.bak`, `.orig`, and `.new` etc. are not executable files, so those extensions should never exist within PATHEXT. Anyhow there's nothing to stop you from renaming them in another way, all you need to do is use a different method of isolating the original extension, you don't need to keep the period.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly there is no `$` wildcard. So it means a literal **$**.

Wildcards are matched against both names of a file. The file with the extension `.txttttt` has a short name extension of `.txt`. Because the first file in the `dir` didn't conflict with another file, and good to be represented by its 8.3 long name, it doesn't have a shortname as it's longname is valid. (PS the second text.txt has leading spaces using `\\?\C:\  test.txt`).

```
C:\>dir /x t*.txt
 Volume in drive C is Windows
 Volume Serial Number is 9EE7-AAA5

 Directory of C:\

17/01/2019  11:23 AM               250              test.txt
26/02/2018  07:30 PM           195,776 TEST~1.TXT     test.txt
21/01/2019  05:50 PM                 5 TEST~2.TXT   test.txtttt
               3 File(s)        196,031 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  752,444,428,288 bytes free
```

See [Command to run a .bat file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41030190/command-to-run-a-bat-file/41049135#41049135)

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me

```
Dir /b *.txt* > fileName.out
```

Comment: No, this will also match `*.txt.exe`