# Getting an unwanted file after executing a bat file

Tags: batch-file, bcp, sqlcmd

I have a batch file that extracts one row from a database and uses that data as a variable to use the value to be a filename, and exports data as text file.

It works fine except for exporting two text files. 
One of the two files is the correct file. 
The other one is the unnecessary file. The filename is ".txt" and has the same data as the first one.

Here is my bat file:

```
SET SQLCMD=sqlcmd -S server -d db -Q "set NOCOUNT 
on; select name from t1" -h-1

FOR /F "usebackq delims=, tokens=1" %%i IN (`%SQLCMD%`) DO (

CALL :PROCESSING %%i
)

:PROCESSING
SET COL1=%1

bcp "SELECT * FROM t1" queryout "C:\Export\%COL1%.txt." -S server -T -c
```

What do I need to fix to get only one file?

Since I am new to coding, if anyone could help, that would be very appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: Should that really read as, `"C:\Export\%COL1%.txt."`?

Comment: Try `Goto :eof` after the closing brackets. See `Goto /?` and `call /?`. You are executing your command an extra time after leaving the loop.

Comment: @Noodles It worked! Thank you so much. What does     Goto /? and call /? do? Where do I put those in the bat file? Could you explain? I went to google but could not get what they do. Sorry I do not know anything :(

Comment: @Compo is that not supposed to? Could you explain why you said that please?

Comment: `call /?` displays help on the `call` command. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41030190/command-to-run-a-bat-file/41049135#41049135 for an intro to Command Prompt.

Comment: Not understanding why you just didn't put the `bcp` command inside the `FOR` command.  You are creating overhead by making the extra call.

Comment: @Noodles Thank you so much for your help. It will help improve my understanding.

Comment: @Squashman I used sqlcmd first to get a value from a table to use as a variable in the bcp. I didn't want an extra file. Do you think I can combine them into one? Is that better?

Comment: Yeah, you can change the `call :processing %%i` line into `bcp "SELECT * FROM t1" queryout "C:\Export\%%i.txt." -S server -T -c` and just delete the processing section altogether

Comment: Instead of making the CALL, put your BCP command there and use the FOR variable in the BCP command. This falls under the K.I.S.S. theory.

Comment: @P002143_k, if the usual construct is `queryout data_file` in my opinion, it's odd for a data file to have either an empty extension, or one which ends with a period suffix, hence the reason for my clarification comment.

Comment: @SomethingDark @Squashman   Hi I put the  `bcp "SELECT * FROM t1" queryout "C:\Export\%%i.txt." -S server -T -c ` in the `DO()` but it does not work. I ran the bat file in command prompt and it works fine and has no error, but does not generate a file. If you could help, I really appreciate that.