# file listing - Including all subfolders with filename, path, date and size

Tags: windows, cmd, filelist

I am trying to get a list of all files within a directory including those within all subfolders.

The columns I would like are the `Filename`, `Path`, `Size` and `Date`.

I have tried to do my own research and come close but not yet hit the full solution.

I can get the filepath and filename together with date and size using this command below, unfortunately I cannot get all the files within a subfolders.

```
dir /t > filelist1.txt
```

This below CMD command does get the filenames from all subfolders but I cannot get it to produce dates.

```
(@For /F "Delims=" %A in ('dir /B/S/A-D') Do @Echo %~fA %~zA) >filelist.txt
```

I thought maybe do this to include dates but it didn't work.

```
(@For /F "Delims=" %A in ('dir /B/S/A/D') Do @Echo %~fA %~zA) >filelist.txt
```

This file also gives me the path and filename together which I can accept (I will use Excel to separate) but is it possible to have the path and filename separated?

Also it is possible to have those columns separated by tab for easier Excel import?

Comment: you seem to know how to use modifiers, so why don't you use `%~dpA` for path and `%~nxA` for filename and `%~tA` for date/time?

Comment: How about `dir /?`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41030190/command-to-run-a-bat-file/41049135#41049135.

Comment: Hi Stephan.....Sorry I am a novice at those DOS commands I am just using what others have used and unable to do that last 20% where I have to cater it for myself.

Comment: bookmark [SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/) and visit it often. Also for a quick overview of what a command can do and it's parameters, see it's help with `/?`, for example `for /?`

Comment: [The Windows command prompt is *NOT* a DOS prompt!](https://scalibq.wordpress.com/2012/05/23/the-windows-command-prompt-is-not-a-dos-prompt/)

Answer (score 0):

This could be done with %~ variables in a cmd.exe batch script. But, it is easier and more readable in PowerShell. The output is in a file named `FileList.csv`.

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse |
    ForEach-Object {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            FileName = $_.Name
            Path = $_.Directory
            Size = $_.Length
            Date = $_.LastWriteTime
        }
    } |
    Export-Csv -Path './FileList.csv' -Delimiter "`t" -Encoding ASCII -NoTypeInformation
```

If you do not want to run the .ps1 file from the .bat script, it can, with enough effort, be put into the .bat file script.

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "Get-ChildItem |" ^
        "ForEach-Object {" ^
                "[PSCustomObject]@{" ^
                "FileName = $_.Name;" ^
                "Path = $_.Directory;" ^
                "Size = $_.Length;" ^
                "Date = $_.LastWriteTime" ^
            "}" ^
        "} |" ^
        "Export-Csv -Path './FileList.csv' -Delimiter "`t" -Encoding ASCII -NoTypeInformation"
```