# Is there a batch equivalent to Linux's "sdiff -s" command?

Tags: batch-file

The computer science class that I'm taking uses a bash script to grade our assignments. However, since many students use Windows, I'm trying to write an equivalent batch file that they can run on their devices to grade their lab.

A really important part of the bash script is
"sdiff -s key_$f out_$f >> details.txt"

It compares the key file and the output file and prints the differences in the details file.

I haven't used bash before and its been a while since I used batch files, so I'm pretty lost.

Bash script:

```
echo ""
echo "Running Diff"
echo "--------"
rm turnin.txt
rm details.txt
for f in file*.txt;
do
    f=${f#tests/}
    cat out_$f >> turnin.txt
    echo "out_$f">> details.txt
    sdiff -s key_$f out_$f >> details.txt
    if [ ${PIPESTATUS[0]} -eq 0 ];
    then
        echo "key_$f and out_$f are identical"
    else
        echo "key_$f and out_$f differ :: check details.txt for details"
    fi
done
echo "--------"
```

Example of details.txt when files are the same:

```
out_file1.txt
out_file2.txt
out_file3.txt
out_file4.txt
out_file5.txt
```

Example of details.txt when some lines of the files are different:

```
out_file1.txt
isBalanced { ( [ ] } ) False                      | isBalanced { ( [ ] } ) True
isBalanced { { ( ) [ { } ] ( [ ] ) } } True       | isBalanced { { ( ) [ { } ] ( [ ] ) } } False
out_file2.txt
out_file3.txt
out_file4.txt
  40 2 4 + 2 2 + - * 4 5 / 6 / -                  |   402 4 + 2 2 + - * 4 5 / 6 / -
  48 36 7 % + 2 -                                 |   48 36 7 2 -
out_file5.txt
```

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Type `fc /?`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41030190/command-to-run-a-bat-file/41049135#41049135 for an intro incl *How to use help*.

Comment: Other suggestions.  If they are running windows, WSL provides 99.9% Linux without a VM.  They could run your bash script without modification.  Windows is primarily UI so suggest that they use something like (free) winmerge to do the same thing.  http://winmerge.org/?lang=en