# How to Play Beep Conditionally?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to play a beep sound if a copy operation fails.

```
copy C:\Amethyst\Original.docx C:\Backup
if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
    echo 
)
```

The sound always plays.

Comment: `if /?` from a command prompt will show you the proper way to test `%ERRORLEVEL5`. What you're using is not it. :-)

Comment: `copy c:\windows\win.ini c:\backup\*.*  || echo ^G` `^g` is entered by pressing Ctrl+G (the bell key on a teletype). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41030190/command-to-run-a-bat-file/41049135#41049135 for `||`.

Comment: From: https://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html:
A better (more logical) method of checking Errorlevels is to use the %ERRORLEVEL% variable:
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 Echo An error was found

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for misunderstanding your question ... 
Here are several solutions:

Switch :

```
if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
  echo ...
)
```

And instead of `if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0` try `if not "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0"` or

```
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" (
    echo Ok
) else (
    echo ...
)
```

* ... to change with the bell

Answer (score -1):

*(Translated from French)*

Hi, 
What you ask is not directly feasible with CMD ... but with NIRCMD.exe it is possible !

[Download Here](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.zip)

- **1)** Unzip `nircmd.zip`
- **2)** Move the 3 files (nircmd.exe, nircmdc.exe, nircmd.chm) into C:/Windows/System32
- **+)** For more help on NIRCMD, type nircmd.chm in the command prompt

For the beep, there are several solutions:
- `nircmd stdbeep` 
will play the default Windows beep
- `nircmd beep [Frequency] [Duration]` 
will play a beep with a frequency of [Frequency] Hz for [Duration] milliseconds
- `nircmd mediaplay [play time] [audio file]` 
will play [audio file] for [play time] milliseconds

I hope I answered your question

Yassin

Comment: The beep isn't the problem (there is a `BEL` character after `echo`, which this site doesn't display) The problem is that the `if` doesn't seem to work (which I can't replicate - except OP set a variable `errorlevel`, which would override the systemvariable).