# Batch file not running, only individual command runs

Tags: batch-file, cmd, ffmpeg, command, command-prompt

I have a batch file of the following code

```
cd C:\xampp\htdocs\Projects\videos\images_compare_english && ffmpeg -framerate .25 -i img-%02d.jpg -i music.mp3 -c:v libx264 -preset veryslow -crf 0 -c:a copy -shortest compare_english\output.mp4
```

The above code has two commands which is separated by `&&`, means the second command will run only after the execution of the first. But it is not running. I am basically combining some images with music. But it is not working. However entering manually one command at a time works. Can anybody help me, what is the problem with command prompt?

Comment: `&&` does not mean only run when previous command is finished. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41030190/command-to-run-a-bat-file/41049135#41049135

Comment: You are in a batch file. Why do you want to chain the commands? Just do new lines.

Comment: It's a [tag:batch-file] not [tag:cmd], so you need to double the **`%`** characters…`%%02d.jpg` instead of `%02d.jpg`.

Comment: ffmpeg not find: img-`%02`d.jpg, img-`%%02`d.jpg, img-`?02`d.jpg, img-`*02`d.jpg

Answer (score 0):

---

- Update - I've tried one by one some possible command option to use file name rename your img-`%0`2d.jpg without remove/rename these characters: `%0`, no success. I fill you need remove `%` from fine name...

  ---

[image]

---

---

Try to rename your img-`%0`2d.jpg file remove/change this `%0`

**`%0`** == is a variable to save name of the bat file itself:

**`%0`** == your_bat_file.bat

**img-`%02`d.jpg**   == **img-`your_bat_file.bat`2d.jpg**

---

```bat
@echo off && setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "_to_push=C:\xampp\htdocs\Projects\videos\images_compare_english"              & rem/ path files mp3/jpg
set "_ffmpegF=C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe"                                            & rem/ path binary ffmpeg
set "_to_save=!_to_push!\compare_english"                                          & rem/ path binary ffmpeg
rem./                                                                    next line & rem/ ffmpeg.exe command
"!_ffmpegF!" -framerate .25 -i "!_to_push!\img-02d.jpg" -i "!_to_push!\music.mp3"  ^
    -c:v libx264 -preset veryslow -crf 0 -c:a copy -shortest "!_to_save!\output.mp4"

endlocal && exit /b
```

---

File name layouts tested with **`ffmepg`** and they resuls from **`ffmpeg`** and **`cmd.exe`**:

```bat
rem/ using %%02d  == img-%02d.jpg
[image2 @ 0000017eeb2eb980] Could find no file with path 'C:\xampp\htdocs\Projects\videos\images_compare_english\img-%02d.jpg' and index in the range 0-4
C:\xampp\htdocs\Projects\videos\images_compare_english\img-%02d.jpg: No such file or directory

 rem/ using ?02d == img-?02d.jpg
[image2 @ 0000027e9792b980] Could find no file with path 'C:\xampp\htdocs\Projects\videos\images_compare_english\img-?02d.jpg' and index in the range 0-4
C:\xampp\htdocs\Projects\videos\images_compare_english\img-?02d.jpg: No such file or directory

rem/ using %%%02d == img-%Q58949386.cmd2d
C:\xampp\htdocs\Projects\videos\images_compare_english\img-%Q58949386.cmd2d.jpg: No such file or directory

rem/ using *02d == img-*02d.jpg
[image2 @ 0000024dc0edb980] Could find no file with path 'C:\xampp\htdocs\Projects\videos\images_compare_english\img-*02d.jpg' and index in the range 0-4
C:\xampp\htdocs\Projects\videos\images_compare_english\img-*02d.jpg: No such file or directory
```

---

[image]

---

---

Get more info about [`%0, %~0, %~d0, %~dp0, %~f0, %~n0, %~x0...`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zainala/2008/08/05/using-0-inside-the-batch-file-to-get-the-file-info/)

Answer (score 0):

Check the `%ERRORLEVEL%` of the previous command just to see if there is anything wrong by using `cd C:\xampp\htdocs\Projects\videos\images_compare_english & echo %errorlevel%` to check if anything is wrong. If the `%ERRORLEVEL%` is 0, then it should work with `&&`, but if it isn't 0, then there is something wrong with that and `&&` won't work.

`&&` means that the next command will run if the `%ERRORLEVEL%` of the previous command is 0. Just use `&` to run two commands in the same line. Also, what is the purpose of doing two commands on one line if you are in a batch file? Just add a new line as Gerhard Barnard said.

https://pastebin.com/nkkCUMKn