# Extract list of path in a file using batch script

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd

Here is my text file:

```
==================================================
Folder            : D:\T\New folder
==================================================

==================================================
Folder            : D:\T\Z-Ai
==================================================

==================================================
Folder            : D:\T\Z-BiN
==================================================
```

I need to extract the paths from this file, so I have something like this:

```
D:\T\New folder 
D:\T\Z-Ai 
D:\T\Z-BiN
```

It seems I should use `findstr TargetWord TargetFile.txt` command. and Also it seems I can use regex like this: `findstr /r "^[a-z][a-z]$ ^[a-z][a-z][a-z]$"`

But I do not know how to loop through found targets or get the list of output. any help is really appreciated.

Comment: `findstr /r "^[a-z][a-z]$ ^[a-z][a-z][a-z]$" < inputfile.txt > outputfile.txt` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41030190/command-to-run-a-bat-file/41049135#41049135

Comment: It is easy, but what you want to do with the result is what I am unsure of, please clarify and I can show you an example.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard I need to use xcopy to copy all contents of folders into another one

Comment: @GerhardBarnard yes the output file is exactly the same as I shown.

Comment: ok, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, you want to use the result to perform an xcopy task, it seems you really  want something like this. Note I used `example.txt` as input file, and `DESTINATION` where you should add your destination, including the relevant `xcopy` switches you require:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2*" %%i in ('type example.txt ^| findstr /i ":\\"') do xcopy "%%~j\*" DESTINATION
```

Alternatively we can use the `findstr` directly on `Folder`

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2*" %%i in ('type example.txt ^| findstr /i "Folder"') do xcopy "%%~j\*" DESTINATION
```

Comment: GREAT and nice and clean. Thank you Gerhard.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this :

```
@echo off
Title Extract list of path in a file using batch script
set "TxtList=MyList.txt"
Set  "OutPutData=Output.txt"
Call :Extract "%TxtList%" "%OutPutData%"
Start "" "%OutPutData%"
Exit
::*****************************************************
:Extract <InputData> <OutPutData>
(
echo Data = WScript.StdIn.ReadAll
echo Data = Extract(Data,"[\w]:(\\[0-9\sA-Za-z\-]*)+"^)
echo WScript.StdOut.WriteLine Data
echo '************************************************
echo Function Extract(Data,Pattern^)
echo    Dim oRE,oMatches,Match,Line
echo    set oRE = New RegExp
echo    oRE.IgnoreCase = True
echo    oRE.Global = True
echo    oRE.Pattern = Pattern
echo    set oMatches = oRE.Execute(Data^)
echo    If not isEmpty(oMatches^) then
echo        For Each Match in oMatches  
echo            Line = Line ^& Trim(Match.Value^) ^& vbcrlf
echo        Next
echo        Extract = Line 
echo    End if
echo End Function
echo '************************************************
)>"%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"
cscript /nologo "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs" < "%~1" > "%~2"
If Exist "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs" Del "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"
exit /b
::****************************************************
```

Answer (score 0):

For Windows. you can use powershell.

```
 select-string -Path c:\tmp\file.txt -Pattern '[A-Z]:(\\[0-9\ A-Za-z\-]*)+' -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value }
```

Comment: cat is not recognized.

Comment: I see. It's windows:

Comment: Technically, this answer doesn't really match the tags attached to the question. In order for it to be considered relevant, you may wish to consider adjusting it, to provide information or show how the OP or future readers can launch/run it from a [tag:batch-file].

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, `For /F` is all you need for the task. *Although using `Type` may be useful in some situations, there's no need to use `find.exe` or `findstr.exe` for this task as you don't need to match a particular glob/pattern*:

```bat
@For /F "EOL==Tokens=2*UseBackQ" %%A In ("TargetFile.txt")Do @"%__AppDir__%xcopy.exe" "%%B" "Destination\" /Options
```

Please note that it may be wise, if there's a chance that one or more of theses `Folder`s do not exist, that you prepend using `If Exist "%%B\"`. Importantly, if each of the lines containing the `Folder` paths, is space padded up to the end of its line, this solution will not work for you.