# Why are commands in batch script "not recognized" which are executed manually fine?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-server-2012

I am writing a batch script that installs some applications from MSI files from the same folder.

When I write those commands in command prompt window, all is fine and all the commands work properly.

But when I write them into the batch script, suddenly most of the commands such as `XCOPY`, `msiexec`, `DISM` result in an error message like:

> 'XCOPY' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

After googling it for a while, I saw a lot of comments related to the environment variable `PATH` which should contain `C:\Windows\system32` and I made sure its included in the `PATH`. Also found a lot of answers about writing the full path which I already tried and it didn't work.

I'm working on Windows server 2012.

This is the code of my batch file:

```
@echo off
set path=C:\                rem default path
rem get the path as parameter to the script:
set argC=0
for %%x in (%*) do Set /A argC+=1
if %argC% gtr 0  (set path=%1%)
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
    echo %me%: something went wrong with input directory
) 
echo Destenation: %path%

SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SET me=%~n0
SET parent=%~dp0
echo %me%: starting installation of Python 2.7 64bit and Apache 64 bit
REM install .net 3.5
DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:NetFx3 /All /LimitAccess /Source:installationMediaDrive:\sources\sxs
msiexec /i ".\py\python-2.7.amd64.msi" TARGETDIR=%path%/Python27 /passive /norestart ADDLOCAL=ALL
mkdir %path%\Apache24
XCOPY /e /Q ".\Apache24" %path%\Apache24
```

Comment: Show us your code

Comment: hey, thanks for the respone, i added code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the batch file should support an optionally specified path to installation directory as first parameter. The code used to check for existence of this optional folder path is very confusing. There are definitely easier methods to check for an optional parameter as it can be seen below.

The main problem is redefining environment variable `PATH` which results in standard console applications of Windows stored in directory `%SystemRoot\System32` and other standard Windows directories are not found anymore by command interpreter `cmd.exe` on execution of the batch file.

In general it is required to specify an application to execute with full path, file name and file extension enclosed in double quotes in case of this complete file specification string contains a space character or one of these characters `` &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~ `` as explained in last paragraph on last output help page on running in a command prompt window `cmd /?`.

But mainly for making it easier for human users to execute manually applications and scripts from within a command prompt window, the Windows command interpreter can also find the application or script to run by itself if specified without path and without file extension.

So if a user enters just `xcopy` or a batch file contains just `xcopy`, the Windows command interpreter searches for a file matching the pattern `xcopy.*` which has a file extension as defined in semicolon separated list of environment variable `PATHEXT` first in current directory and if no suitable file found next in all directories in semicolon separated list of environment variable `PATH`.

There are 3 environment variables `PATH`:

1. The **system** `PATH` as stored in Windows registry under:

   ```
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment
   ```

   The folder paths in **system** `PATH` are used by default for all processes independent on used account.
2. The **user** `PATH` as stored in Windows registry under:

   ```
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Environment
   ```

   The folder paths in **user** `PATH` are used by default only for all processes running using the account on which the **user** `PATH` was set.
3. The **local** `PATH` just hold in memory in currently active environment of running process.

The **system** and the **user** `PATH` are concatenated by Windows to a single **local** `PATH` for processes.

Every time a process starts a new process like Windows Explorer starting Windows command interpreter for execution of a batch file, a **copy** of the environment table of currently running process is created by Windows for the new process. So whatever a process changes on its own local copy of environment variables has no effect on all other already running processes. The local changes on the environment variables are effective only on own process and all processes started by the process modifying its variables.

On starting the batch file the variables `PATH` and `PATHEXT` have the values as displayed on running in a command prompt window opened under same user account as used on starting the batch file the command `set PATH` listing all variables starting with `PATH` case-insensitive in name.

Now let us look on the second line of the batch file:

```
set path=C:\                rem default path
```

This line redefines the **local** `PATH` environment variable. Therefore the environment variable `PATH` being effective for the command process executing the batch file and all applications started by this batch file does not contain anymore `C:\Windows\System32;C:\Windows;...`, but contains now just this very strange single folder path.

```
C:\                rem default path
```

`rem` is an internal command of `cmd.exe` and must be written on a separate line. There is no line comment possible in batch code like `//` in C++ or JavaScript. For help on this command run in a command prompt window `rem /?`.

On running the batch file without an installation folder path as first argument, the result is that Windows command interpreter searches for `dism.*`, `msiexec.*` and `xcopy.*` just in current directory as there is surely no directory with name `rem default path` with lots of spaces/tabs at beginning in root of drive `C:`.

Conclusion: It is no good idea to use `path` as variable name for the installation folder path.

Another mistake in batch code is using `%1%` to specify the first argument of the batch file. This is wrong as the arguments of the batch file are referenced with `%1`, `%2`, ... Run in a command prompt window `call /?` for help on referencing arguments of a batch file and which possibilities exist like `%~dp0` used below to get drive and path of argument 0 which is the batch file name, i.e. the path of the folder containing the currently running batch file.

I suggest using this batch code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions
set "SourcePath=%~dp0"
set "BatchName=%~n0"
if "%~1" == "" (
    echo %BatchName% started without an installation folder path.
    set "InstallPath=C:\"
    goto StartInstalls
)

rem Get installation folder path from first argument
rem of batch file without surrounding double quotes.
set "InstallPath=%~1"

rem Replace all forward slashes by backslashes in case of installation
rem path was passed to the batch file with wrong directory separator.
set "InstallPath=%InstallPath:/=\%"

rem Append a backslash on installation path
rem if not already ending with a backslash.
if not "%InstallPath:~-1%" == "\" set "InstallPath=%InstallPath%\"

:StartInstalls
echo %BatchName%: Installation folder: %InstallPath%

echo/
echo %BatchName%: Installing .NET 3.5 ...
DISM.exe /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:NetFx3 /All /LimitAccess /Source:installationMediaDrive:\sources\sxs

echo/
echo %BatchName%: Installing Python 2.7 64-bit ...
%SystemRoot%\System32\msiexec.exe /i "%SourcePath%py\python-2.7.amd64.msi" TARGETDIR="%InstallPath%Python27" /passive /norestart ADDLOCAL=ALL

echo/
echo %BatchName%: Installing Apache 2.4 64-bit ...
mkdir "%InstallPath%Apache24"
%SystemRoot%\System32\xcopy.exe "%SourcePath%\Apache24" "%InstallPath%Apache24\" /C /E /H /I /K /Q /R /Y >nul

endlocal
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?` ... for explanation of `%~dp0`, `%~n0` and `%~1`.
- `dism /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `msiexec /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `xcopy /?`

And read also

- the Microsoft TechNet article [Using command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx),
- the Microsoft support article [Testing for a Specific Error Level in Batch Files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/69576),
- the answer on [change directory command cd ..not working in batch file after npm install](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38676582/3074564) and the answers referenced there for understanding how `setlocal` and `endlocal` really work and
- the answer on [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564) for understanding why using `set "variable=value"`.

And last take a look on:

- [SS64.com - A-Z index of the Windows CMD command line](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Microsoft's command-line reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands)
- [Windows Environment Variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Windows) (Wikipedia article)

The administrator of a Windows server should twist everything written here and on the referenced pages round one's little finger.

Comment: WOW! thank you very much! i didn't realized how its work completely. It's really helped and solved my issues.
one more thing that made some of the commands available is to call them directly from sys32 folder.