# Password system does not work

Tags: batch-file

Here is the code I am trying to solve:

```
set /p password= Password (Put in Guest if guest login):
if %password% == %pass% goto desktop
if not %password% == %pass% goto bootscreentwo
if %password% == Guest goto ltddesktop
:desktop
```

it is for a "Mini operating system" made in batch.

Comment: Indeed, that is some code. Can you elaborate on what "does not work" means? Otherwise, it's going to be very hard to help you.

Comment: Traditional responses to "it doesn't work" when your code looks like that are "use delayed expansion" and "put quotes around both %password% and %pass%", but it's honestly too hard to tell with the snippet you've posted.

Answer (score 2):

The code does not work if the user just hits <kbd>RETURN</kbd> or <kbd>ENTER</kbd> resulting in environment variable `password` still not being defined as not defined with an initial value above line with `set /p`.

This results on **IF** condition with immediate expansion of environment variable `password` and with `pass` having value `xxx` in the command line:

```
if == xxx goto desktop
```

The left string is missing and therefore batch execution is exited because of a syntax error as it can be seen on running the batch file without `@echo off` at top of the batch file from within a command prompt window instead of double clicking on the batch file.

Also if the entered string contains for example `|` or `&` or `<` or `>` the immediate expansion of environment variable `password` result on parsing the **IF** condition line in a syntax error with an immediate exit of batch file execution.

The common solution to get characters with special meaning interpreted as literal characters is putting both strings to compare in double quotes. The double quotes are also compared by **IF** and not just the string between the double quotes. Therefore it is necessary to double quote both strings.

```
if "%password%" == "%pass%" goto desktop
if not "%password%" == "%pass%" goto bootscreentwo
if "%password%" == "Guest" goto ltddesktop
```

Which characters require double quotes around a string is explained in help of Windows command interpreter output by running in a command prompt window `cmd /?` in last paragraph on last output help page. The [redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) `>`, `<` and `|` are missing in this list as those characters can't be used in file names.

But there is still a problem even on using double quotes around the strings to compare if the batch file user enters a string containing 1 or more double quotes as this results with immediate environment variable expansion again in a syntax error on execution of **IF** command line.

The solution is using delayed environment variable expansion as explained by help of command **SET** output on running in a command prompt window `set /?`.

First suggestion for the batch code on where the user has to enter `guest` for using guest access:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "pass=xxx"

:EnterPassword
set "password="
set /P "password=Enter "Guest" for guest login. Password: "
if "!password!" == "" goto EnterPassword

rem Case-sensitive password string compare using delayed expansion.
if "!password!" == "!pass!" goto desktop

rem Case-insensitive password string compare using delayed expansion.
if /I "!password!" == "Guest" goto ltddesktop

echo bootscreentwo
goto :EOF

:desktop
echo Label desktop
goto :EOF

:ltddesktop
echo Label ltddesktop
goto :EOF
```

Windows command interpreter does implicitly do an `endlocal` on exiting batch file execution on executing `goto :EOF` resulting in restoring previous command process environment.

Second suggestion for batch code with `guest` being default password:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "pass=xxx"

:EnterPassword
set "password=guest"
set /P "password=Press ENTER for guest login. Password: "

rem Case-insensitive password string compare using delayed expansion.
if /I "!password!" == "Guest" goto ltddesktop

rem Case-sensitive password string compare using delayed expansion.
if "!password!" == "!pass!" goto desktop

echo bootscreentwo
goto :EOF

:desktop
echo Label desktop
goto :EOF

:ltddesktop
echo Label ltddesktop
goto :EOF
```

Please note that enabled delayed expansion results in interpreting `!` anywhere in batch code as beginning of an environment variable reference. So be careful on using `!` for example in an **ECHO** line as the exclamation mark must be escaped to be interpreted as literal character. It would be best to use `endlocal` before further processing the batch file if the values of `password` and `pass` are no longer needed after this batch code block.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "pass=xxx"

:EnterPassword
set "password=guest"
set /P "password=Press ENTER for guest login. Password: "

rem Case-insensitive password string compare using delayed expansion.
if /I "!password!" == "Guest" endlocal & goto ltddesktop

rem Case-sensitive password string compare using delayed expansion.
if "!password!" == "!pass!" endlocal & goto desktop

endlocal
echo bootscreentwo with pass and password not defined anymore.
goto :EOF

:desktop
echo Label desktop with pass and password not defined anymore.
goto :EOF

:ltddesktop
echo Label ltddesktop with pass and password not defined anymore.
goto :EOF
```

`pass` and `password` are not defined anymore after the string compares, except those two environment variables existed already before execution of **SETLOCAL** command in second line in which case their original values are restored by **ENDLOCAL**. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38676582/3074564) for details about the commands **SETLOCAL** and **ENDLOCAL**.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`