# Pass environment variables to subshell CMD

Tags: batch-file, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a problem in my `gitlab-ci.yml` on Windows. I launch `phpunit` with environments variables.
So, I have a variable like:

```
PHPUNIT : %SOURCE_PATH%\cgi-bin\php.exe %PHPUNIT_PATH%
```

And some variables are declared before:

```
SOURCE_PATH: 'C:\Source'
PHPUNIT_PATH: '"%SOURCE_PATH%\cgi-bin\tests\__init\tools\phpunit.phar"'
```

But when I use the **CALL** command, Windows doesn't resolve the variable inside the other variable.

So if I do:

```
CALL Echo %PHPUNIT%
```

I have:

```
C:\Source\cgi-bin\php.exe "%SOURCE_PATH%\cgi-bin\tests\__init\tools\phpunit.phar"
```

I think this is because of `%SOURCE_PATH%` doesn't exist in **CALL** context.

But I could not find out how to pass the environment variables in the **CALL**. And I could not find another way to do this, too. (If I don't use **CALL**, the **gitlab-ci** stops when the inside script exits.)

I wish you can help me ...

Somethings to know.

My script is launched by **gitlab-ci** runner, so it is started by:

```
setlocal enableextensions
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set nl=^
```

And I can't change this.

I can use PowerShell if needed, or if you know another work around. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This batch file demonstrates on execution the problem and offers a solution.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
cls
set "SOURCE_PATH=C:\Source"
set "PHPUNIT_PATH="%%SOURCE_PATH%%\cgi-bin\tests\__init\tools\phpunit.phar""
echo %SOURCE_PATH%\cgi-bin\php.exe %PHPUNIT_PATH%
echo/
echo Reference to environment variable SOURCE_PATH in environment
echo variable PHPUNIT_PATH is not expanded on running php.exe.
echo/
echo Solution:
echo/
echo Explicitly set environment variable PHPUNIT_PATH once more with
echo its own value with using additionally the command CALL to expand
echo all variable references inside the variable value.
echo/
call set "PHPUNIT_PATH=%PHPUNIT_PATH%"
echo %SOURCE_PATH%\cgi-bin\php.exe %PHPUNIT_PATH%
echo/
endlocal
pause
```

Don't run **SETLOCAL** more than once for defining the command line environment with specifying the parameters `EnableExtensions` and `EnableDelayedExpansion`. Both can be specified on running **SETLOCAL** only once. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38676582/3074564) for a detailed explanation what the commands **SETLOCAL** and **ENDLOCAL** do which should make it clear why it is not advisable to run **SETLOCAL** more often than really needed.

And enable delayed expansion only when really needed as exclamation marks in text to process or directory/file names or parameter strings are handled not anymore as literal character with delayed expansion enabled.

Comment: Thanks you . (That's the only important word)

Answer (score 0):

Your Question is Not so much clear... But, I may guess that - Your inbetween Scripts are using '**Exit**' at the end. SO, Replace it with ***Exit /B***

Or Try to Use **'Start'** Instead of **Call**... (**Start /B ...** - Check '**Start /?'**)

Comment: I can't use **Exit /b** ... because, for example, some times I use some tools like phpunit (So I don't control the code) . 

I have tried "start", but same problem, I have an error saying **%SOURCE_PATH%\cgi-bin\php.exe is not found** . I think, windows resolve the var : `%PHPUNIT% => %SOURCE_PATH%\cgi-bin\php.exe %PHPUNIT_PATH%`

But, inside, windows don't resolve the variable `%SOURCE_PATH%` .

Comment: Yup, Because '%PHPUnit% is not predefined variable in windows. and, so do %Source_Path%. So, Please keep in mind to define these variables first using **Set** Command. And, Don't Forget to use the **Double Quotes** ("") Aorund the Path ...If your path contains Spaces, even though - CMD gievs Error sometimes.

Comment: yes I know, but gitlab define (using set), the vars. So when I define %PHPUNIT%, %SOURCEPATH% exist