# Is it a best practice to change the current work directory in the batch file?

Tags: batch-file, command, working-directory

I have a batch file where I call one application by passing certain arguments.

Here is the content of my sample.batch file

```
cd C:\Program Files\MyApplication
"C:\Program Files\MyApplication\Application.exe" -e -p "Application Projects/Testing/General/Notepad" -rm "Close Notepad"
```

Here I need to change my current working directory to the folder where Application.exe lives so that It finds certain required JARs which is located in that folder.Is it best practice to do so?Changing the current work directory before executing a batch file.

Comment: note, `cd` has the useful `/d` parameter. `pushd`/`popd` is another option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One method is what [Magoo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2128947/magoo) and [Stephan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2152082/stephan) have suggested already:

```
pushd "%ProgramFiles%\MyApplication"

rem Other commands.

popd
```

This solution works even for UNC paths with command extensions enabled as by default as **PUSHD** temporarily maps the network share to a drive letter and makes this network drive the current directory.

Another solution is using **SETLOCAL**, **CD** and **ENDLOCAL** which has the advantage of all modifications of environment variables, command extensions and delayed expansion done by the commands between `setlocal` and `endlocal` don't matter for the commands after `endlocal` command line.

```
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
cd /D "%ProgramFiles%\MyApplication"

rem Other commands running in their own environment, here running with command
rem extensions explicitly enabled and delayed expansion explicitly disabled.

endlocal
```

The command **ENDLOCAL** restores also the current directory as being set on execution of **SETLOCAL**.

See the answer on [change directory command cd ..not working in batch file after npm install](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38676582/3074564) with more details about **PUSHD** (push directory), **POPD** (pop directory), **SETLOCAL** (setup local environment), **CD** (change directory) and **ENDLOCAL** (end local environment).

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `cd /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `rem /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `popd /?`
- `pushd /?`

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
pushd C:\Program Files\MyApplication
...
popd
```

as another choice.

best practice is a matter of both opinion and circumstance