# Why does a batch file switching current directory for command prompt not work on using SETLOCAL command?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am running the following batch script from within a command prompt window to go to a specific folder.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL

set ispyfolder=true
if not "%~1"=="py" if not "%~1"=="pyfolder" set ispyfolder=false
if "%ispyfolder%"=="true" (
    C:
    cd C:\Users\ankagraw\AppData\Local\Continuum
)
```

This code doesn't work when SETLOCAL is there (2nd line). The current directory is the same as before running the batch file from within a command prompt window. If I remove this line, then the script works fine.

I have named the script `go2`. So I want to call it this way:

```
go2 pyfolder
```

I want to use SETLOCAL to avoid touching the global environment variables by mistake.

I think I am making a very simple mistake. But I am new to scripting and therefore can't figure it out.

Answer (score 4):

Your batch code works. I think the real problem is the **ENDLOCAL** command used after the posted block before the other commands of the batch file are processed by Windows command interpreter.

**ENDLOCAL** is executed implicitly by Windows command interpreter in case of the batch file does not contain more commands before terminating execution of the batch file which is important to know when the batch file is executed from within a command prompt window and the expected behavior is that the current directory of the already running command process should be modified by the batch file.

Let us look on the improved batch code below:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set "ispyfolder=true"
if /I not "%~1" == "py" if /I not "%~1" == "pyfolder" set "ispyfolder=false"
if not defined LOCALAPPDATA set "LOCALAPPDATA=%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local"
if "%ispyfolder%" == "true" echo cd /D "%LOCALAPPDATA%\Continuum"

rem Other commands in this local environment like the one below.
echo 1: Current directory is: %CD%

endlocal
rem Commands executed in previous environment with previous current directory.
echo 2: Current directory is: %CD%
```

The reason for using twice `set "variable=value"` is explained by answer on [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564)

The two string comparisons with first batch file argument are made case-insensitive in this improved code by using twice option `/I` of command **IF**.

**LOCALAPPDATA** is a predefined [Windows environment variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Windows) since Windows Vista introducing the local application data directory. On Windows XP there is by default no local application data directory and therefore also no **LOCALAPPDATA** environment variable. However, I added a line to define this environment variable in local environment in case of not being defined which is most likely not necessary on your computer.

The command **CD** has the option `/D` to change **drive**, too.

Read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38676582/3074564) for details about the commands **SETLOCAL** and **ENDLOCAL**.

Then run this batch file from within a command prompt window with `C:\Users\ankagraw` as current directory with `py` or `pyfolder` as first parameter. You get the output:

```
1: Current directory is: C:\Users\ankagraw\AppData\Local\Continuum
2: Current directory is: C:\Users\ankagraw
```

It can be seen here that the command **ENDLOCAL** restores also the current directory. And this might be your problem with your batch file with command lines below `endlocal` or on executing the batch file as posted from within a command prompt window.

The solution is replacing the command line `endlocal` by the line below or adding this command line if the batch file does not contain anything else.

```
endlocal & cd /D "%CD%"
```

The environment variable **CD** is expanded here by Windows command interpreter using the current value of it before executing the first command **ENDLOCAL**. So executed is on your computer with batch file started with parameter being `py` or `pyfolder` the command line:

```
endlocal & cd /D "C:\Users\ankagraw\AppData\Local\Continuum"
```

**ENDLOCAL** deletes the local environment variables table and restores the previous environment variables table, restores the states for command extensions and delayed expansion and restores also the previous current directory. But next command **CD** is executed to change the current directory once again to the directory as it was before in previous command environment.

So I suggest to use on your computer:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "ispyfolder=true"
if /I not "%~1" == "py" if /I not "%~1" == "pyfolder" set "ispyfolder=false"
if "%ispyfolder%" == "true" echo cd /D "%LOCALAPPDATA%\Continuum"
endlocal & cd /D "%CD%"
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `cd /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `if /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Answer (score 0):

**To activate an Anaconda environment in a batch file**, this gist worked perfectly for me under Windows x64:

https://gist.github.com/maximlt/531419545b039fa33f8845e5bc92edd6

The key lines for the batch file are:

```
set CONDAPATH=C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3
rem If this doesn't work, try "conda env list" e.g. C:\Users\%USERNAME%\miniconda3
set ENVNAME=someenv
if %ENVNAME%==base (set ENVPATH=%CONDAPATH%) else (set ENVPATH=%CONDAPATH%\envs\%ENVNAME%)
call %CONDAPATH%\Scripts\activate.bat %ENVPATH%
```

p.s. This is an answer for this duplicate question (which points here): "[activate conda environment from batch file and stay activated? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59851477/activate-conda-environment-from-batch-file-and-stay-activated)"