# Why is an exclamation mark not passed when calling other script?

Tags: batch-file, special-characters

This is the output of my two scripts. The first one calls the other and delivers a filename as `%1`

```
D:\VIDEOS\SHORTS>for %v in (*) do call namer "%v"

D:\VIDEOS\SHORTS>call namer "10 Products You’ll Never Buy Again Knowing How They Are Made!.mp4"

D:\VIDEOS\SHORTS>echo "10 Products You’ll Never Buy Again Knowing How They Are Made.mp4"   | find /i ".tmp"   1>nul  && exit /b
```

The `echo` uses `"%~nx1"`.

My question is: Why does the exclamation mark disappear?

This started happening yesterday, but I'm not sure what I could've done to cause this. It's part of a massive batch script cluster, all of which I can't post here due to size limits so ask for additional details or generalize.

edit: requested file namer.cmd

```
set "full=" & set "file=" & set "name=" & set "type=" & set "year=" & set "episode=" & set "strict=" & set "loose="
echo "%~nx1" | find /i ".tmp" >nul && exit /b
set "file=%~n1"

:: =============================================================================================================================
::      1. file VALIDATOR
:: =============================================================================================================================

set "original=%file%"
set "file=%file:!=%"
set "file=%file:#=%"
set "file=%file: _ = - %"
set "file=%file:’='%"
set "file=%file:“='%"
set "file=%file:”='%"
set "file=%file:[=(%"
set "file=%file:]=)%"
set "file=%file:_= %"
set "file=%file:—=-%"
set "file=%file:  = %"
set "file=%file:  = %"
set "file=%file:&=and%"

:: exclamation point has to be removed before we enable delayed expansion
if not "%file%"=="%original%" ren "%~1" "%file%%~x1" 2>nul && echo validated "%file%%~x1"
if not "%file%"=="%original%" if exist "%original%" ren "%~1" "%file% - copy%~x1" && echo validated "%file% - copy%~x1"
if not "%file%"=="%original%" if exist "%original%" ren "%~1" "%file% - copy 2%~x1" && echo validated "%file% - copy 2%~x1"

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "original=!file!"
set "file=!file:%%=_percent!"
if not "%file%"=="%original%" ren "%~dp1%original%%~x1" "for /f "delims=" %%v in ('where /r "d:\videos" "%strict%*" 2^>nul') do" && echo validated "%original%"

set "original=!file!"
:: this needs to separated in order to add s01 tag if no season tag present
for /l %%s in (0,1,9) do set "file=!file:series.%%s.=S0%%s!"
for /l %%e in (0,1,9) do set "file=!file:%%eof2=E0%%e!"
for /l %%e in (0,1,9) do set "file=!file:%%eof3=E0%%e!"
for /l %%e in (0,1,9) do set "file=!file:%%eof4=E0%%e!"
for /l %%e in (0,1,9) do set "file=!file:%%eof5=E0%%e!"
for /l %%e in (0,1,9) do set "file=!file:%%eof6=E0%%e!"
for /l %%e in (0,1,9) do set "file=!file:%%eof7=E0%%e!"
for /l %%e in (0,1,9) do set "file=!file:%%eof8=E0%%e!"
for /l %%e in (0,1,9) do set "file=!file:%%eof9=E0%%e!"
:: if file has changed but no season tag present add s01
if not "%file%"=="%original%" echo "%file%" | find /i "s0" >nul || set "file=!file:E0=S01E0!"
if not "%file%"=="%original%" ren "%~dp1%original%%~x1" "%file%%~x1" && echo validated "%original%"

:: =============================================================================================================================
::      2. EXTRAPOLATOR
:: =============================================================================================================================

:extrapolate
set "type=" & set "year=" & set "ss=" & set "ep=" & set "episode="
set "name=%file%"
echo "%name%"| find " " >nul || set "name=%name:.= %" & rem if no spaces then then safer to replace dots

:: if short do complete skip of movie/series extrapolator breakdown
echo "%~n1" | find /i "trailer" >nul && set "type=misc" && goto skipyear
echo "%~p1" | find /i "\shorts\" >nul && set "type=misc" && goto skipyear
echo "%~p1" | find /i "\movies\" >nul && set "type=film" && goto skipss
echo "%~p1" | find /i "\series\" >nul && set "type=show"

:: episode number: last tag first
FOR /L %%e IN (100,1,199) DO (
 SET "modname=!name:E%%e=!"
 IF "!modname!" neq "%name%" (
  SET "setcmd=set name=!name:E%%e=& set ep=E%%e& set type=show& rem !"
  GOTO gotep
 )
)
FOR /L %%e IN (10,1,99) DO (
 SET "modname=!name:E%%e=!"
 IF "!modname!" neq "%name%" (
  SET "setcmd=set name=!name:E%%e=& set ep=E%%e& set type=show& rem !"
  GOTO gotep
 )
 SET "modname=!name:E0%%e=!"
 IF "!modname!" neq "%name%" (
  SET "setcmd=set name=!name:E0%%e=& set ep=E0%%e& set type=show& rem !"
  GOTO gotep
 )
)

FOR /L %%e IN (0,1,9) DO (
 SET "modname=!name:E0%%e=!"
 IF "!modname!" neq "%name%" (
  SET "setcmd=set name=!name:E0%%e=& set ep=E0%%e& set type=show& rem !"
  GOTO gotep
 )
 SET "modname=!name:E00%%e=!"
 IF "!modname!" neq "%name%" (
  SET "setcmd=set name=!name:E00%%e=& set ep=E00%%e& set type=show& rem !"
  GOTO gotep
 )
 SET "modname=!name:%%eof=!"
 IF "!modname!" neq "%name%" (
  SET "setcmd=set name=!name:%%eof=& set ep=E0%%e& set type=show& rem !"
  GOTO gotep
 )
 SET "modname=!name:x0%%e=!" 
 IF "!modname!" neq "%name%" (
  SET "setcmd=set name=!name:x0%%e=& set ep=E0%%e& set type=show& rem !"
  GOTO gotep
 )
)

GOTO skipep
:gotep
%setcmd%
:skipep

:: season number: second to last tag second
FOR /L %%e IN (0,1,9) DO (
 SET "modname=!name:S0%%e=!"
 IF "!modname!" neq "%name%" (
  SET "setcmd=set name=!name:S0%%e=& set ss=S0%%e& set type=show& rem !"
  GOTO gotss
 )
)
FOR /L %%e IN (10,1,99) DO (
 SET "modname=!name:S%%e=!"
 IF "!modname!" neq "%name%" (
  SET "setcmd=set name=!name:S%%e=& set ss=S%%e& set type=show& rem !"
  GOTO gotss
 )
)
FOR /L %%e IN (0,1,9) DO (
 SET "modname=!name:series.%%e=!"
 IF "!modname!" neq "%name%" (
  SET "setcmd=set name=!name:series.%%e=& set ss=S0%%e& set type=show& rem !"
  GOTO gotss
 )
)

GOTO skipss
:gotss
%setcmd%
:skipss

if defined ep if not defined ss set ss=S01
set "episode=%ss%%ep%"

:: year number: first tag last (first with brackets so not to confuse with imdb tag)
FOR /L %%e IN (1960,1,2020) DO (
 SET "modname=!name:(%%e)=!"
 IF "!modname!" neq "%name%" (
  SET "setcmd=set name=!name:(%%e)=& set year=%%e& if not defined type set type=film& rem !"
  GOTO gotyear
 )
)
FOR /L %%e IN (1960,1,2020) DO (
 SET "modname=!name:%%e=!"
 IF "!modname!" neq "%name%" (
  SET "setcmd=set name=!name:%%e=& set year=%%e& if not defined type set type=film& rem !"
  GOTO gotyear
 )
)
GOTO skipyear
:gotyear
%setcmd%
:skipyear

if not defined type set type=misc

:: other trimming for misc etc
set name=%name: - copy=&rem %
set name=%name: (1)=&rem %
set name=%name: (2)=&rem %
set name=%name: (3)=&rem %
set name=%name: [1]=&rem %
set name=%name: [2]=&rem %
set name=%name:360p=&rem %
set name=%name:480p=&rem %
set name=%name:720p=&rem %
set name=%name:1080p=&rem %
set name=%name:2160p=&rem %

:: changes for general use
set "name=%name: - = %"
set "name=%name:  = %"

:: trim last useless letter from name
set "name=%name%endtrimmer"
set "name=%name:(endtrimmer=endtrimmer%"
set "name=%name:[endtrimmer=endtrimmer%"
set "name=%name:.endtrimmer=endtrimmer%"
set "name=%name:-endtrimmer=endtrimmer%"
set "name=%name: endtrimmer=endtrimmer%"
set "name=%name: endtrimmer=%"
set "name=%name:_endtrimmer=%"
set "name=%name:endtrimmer=%"

:: set strings
if "%type%"=="misc" set "strict=%name: =?%"
if "%type%"=="film" if defined year set "strict=%name: =?%?(%year%)"
:: caution: this allows movie to be renamed without year tag
:: if "%type%"=="film" if not defined year set "strict=%name: =?%"
if "%type%"=="show" if defined year set "strict=%name: =?%?(%year%)?%episode%"
if "%type%"=="show" if not defined year set "strict=%name: =?%?%episode%"
if "%type%"=="show" if defined year set "loose=%name: =?%?(%year%)?s"
if "%type%"=="show" if not defined year set "loose=%name: =?%?s"

FOR %%a IN (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) DO SET "name=!name:%%a=%%a!"
endlocal & set "full=%~dp1%file%%~x1" & set "file=%file%%~x1" & set "name=%name%" & set "type=%type%" & set "year=%year%" & set "episode=%ss%%ep%" & set "strict=%strict%" & set "loose=%loose%"

:: declare (disable never delete)
echo extrapolated %type% "%strict:?= %"

:: =============================================================================================================================
::      3. FILEBOT MODERATOR
:: =============================================================================================================================

:: if rename not needed exit
if "%type%"=="misc" exit /b
if "%~2"=="-norename" exit /b

:: if already renamed we are done here
echo "%file%" | find /i " tt" >nul && exit /b

:: prep fake temp file
set tempdir=%temp%\%date:~3,2%%date:~6,2%%date:~11,2%%time:~1,1%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%%time:~9,2%
mkdir "%tempdir%" && copy /y nul "%tempdir%\%file%" >nul

:: variables (to shorten lines)
if "%type%"=="film" set cf=--db TheMovieDb --format "{n} ({y}) {director} {genres} r{rating} {vf} {vc} {ac} {imdbid}"
if "%type%"=="show" set cf=--db TheTVDb --format "{n} {s00e00} {t} {vf} {vc} {ac}-mallSanta"

:: rename fake temp file
filebot -rename "%tempdir%\%file%" --q "%name% %year%" %cf% >nul 2>nul

:: new name into variable
for /r "%tempdir%" %%i in (*) do set "new=%%~nxi"

:: declare failure
if "%file%"=="%new%" echo failed, reason: && filebot -rename "%tempdir%\%file%" --log warning --q "%name% %year%" %cf% & exit /b

:: check all strings against renamed orphan fake file and if successful rename 4real
for /f "delims=" %%v in ('where "%tempdir%:%strict%*" 2^>nul') do goto 4real
for /f "delims=" %%v in ('where "%tempdir%:%strict:s?='s?%*" 2^>nul') do goto 4real
for /f "delims=" %%v in ('where "%tempdir%:%strict:?-?=?%*" 2^>nul') do goto 4real

:: declare failure and confirm override
echo.
echo file "%file%" was renamed
echo to a "%new%", which was unexpected,
:: try the interactive command prompt mode in filebot?
choice /t 20 /c yn /n /d n /m "override and approve this rename? [Y]es or [N]o: "
if "%errorlevel%"=="1" goto 4real
exit /b

:4real
filebot -rename "%~dp1%file%" --q "%name% %year%" %cf% >nul 2>nul
if not exist "%~dp1%file%" echo successfully renamed "%file%"

:: validate the new file (maybe just send to validate with a -norename? takes longer but clearer code
set "original=%file%"
set "file=%file:!=%"
set "file=%file:#=%"
set "file=%file: _ = - %"
set "file=%file:’='%"
set "file=%file:“='%"
set "file=%file:”='%"
set "file=%file:_= %"
set "file=%file:—=-%"
set "file=%file:  = %"
set "file=%file:  = %"
set "file=%file:&=and%"
if not "%file%"=="%original%" ren "%~1" "%file%" && echo validated "%original%"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "original=!file!"
set "file=!file:%%= percent!"
if not "%file%"=="%original%" ren "%~dp1%original%%~x1" "%file%" && echo validated "%original%"
endlocal
exit /b
```

it (1.) removes problematic characters from the filename (2.) from filename extrapolates video `name`, `year`, other variables, then (3.) does a supervised `filebot` rename. the `setlocal` and `endlocal` bits look good. could it be the problem is inherited from yet another script?

Comment: How about using `^!` when delayedexpansion is off?

Comment: you can use `^!` with delayedexpansion off or just use `^^!` when using `enable delayedexpansion` unless the ! is inside quotes, then still you only need to use `^!`

Comment: how will this `^!` help when it's in the unknown filename? seems like fixing the issue is better than hacking through a mediary variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have enabled delay environment variable expansion with `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` somewhere above the **ECHO** line in batch script `namer`.

Therefore the exclamation mark is not further interpreted as literal character, but as begin/end of a variable reference expanded delayed.

We would need the batch code of `namer` batch file to help you solving this issue.

It looks like the line is for checking if the file contains .tmp, i.e. has the file extension `.tmp` and if this is the case, ignore the file.

I suggest to change in your first batch file

```
for %%v in (*) do call namer "%%v"
```

to

```
for %%I in (*) do if /I not "%%~xI" == ".tmp" call "%~dp0namer.cmd" "%%I"
```

Then files with file extension `.tmp` are not processed at all by `namer` batch file.

Run in a command prompt window `set /?` for more information about delayed expansion and `for /?` for help on `%~xI` (file extension of file) as well as `if /?` for help on command **IF** and `call /?` for help on `%~dp0`.

It is also possible to use in `namer.cmd`:

```
if /I "%~x1" == ".tmp" goto :EOF
```

This exits processing of the batch file `namer.cmd` if the file extension of first argument is `.tmp` (compared case-insensitive). For this comparison it does not matter if delayed expansion is enabled or not. See also answer on [Where does GOTO :EOF return to?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37518000/3074564)

---

If `.tmp` is not the file extension of the file, but is just somewhere within file name, it is possible to use an **IF** with string substitution.

Example for batch file `namer.cmd`.

```
set "FileName=%~nx1"
if not "%FileName:.tmp=%" == "%FileName%" goto :EOF
```

The first line assigns file name with extension but without path to environment variable `FileName`.

The second line compares case-sensitive the file name string in which all occurrences of `.tmp` are replaced case-insensitive with an empty string with the file name string not modified at all. The two compared strings are not equal if the file name string really contains `.tmp` 1 or more times resulting in exiting processing of the batch file.

In other words the **IF** condition checks if a string assigned to an environment variable contains case-insensitive the string specified between `:` and `=`.

That is similar to using in **C**:

```
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc > 1)
    {
        /* Does first argument contain the string ".tmp"? */
        if(strstr(argv[1],".tmp") != NULL) return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Function [strstr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strstr/) is case-sensitive.

Comment: actually the .tmp is part of the full filename not only extension. this is to prevent temporary YTD files from being processed. it uses `.tmp` extension for the tracks while downloading and then combines them into `*.tmp.mp4`. namer.cmd added.

Comment: is there any way to check if delayed expanion is enabled or not?

Comment: @bricktop Yes, for example with `if "!" == "" echo Delayed expansion is enabled.` The __IF__ condition is only true if delayed expansion is enabled, otherwise the two compared strings are never equal.

Comment: I started a major overhaul on all 11 script in this cluster to get rid of these `setlocal` issues I am now having an issue where the variables namer.cmd extrapolates are not carried over to none of the four scripts that do the requests. I broke the script down to three separate scripts and made sure `endlocal` is not used anywhere, only `disabledelayedexpansion` but the variables still disappear when returning to the script that requested them. I feel like I'm taking crazy pills.

Comment: @bricktop Help output on running in a command prompt window `setlocal /?` explains: *When the end of a batch file script is reached, an implicit ENDLOCAL is executed for any outstanding SETLOCAL commands issued by that batch script.* So your set of batch files should not make use of `setlocal` wherever possible and pass environment variables over local environment boundary. For example after `set "file=!file:%%=_percent!"` in `namer.cmd` use `endlocal & set "file=%file%"` to set `file` in restored environment to value of `file` in discarded environment.

Comment: thanks, I thought I could use `setlocal disabledelayedexpansion` instead of `endlocal` to quit the environment but keep the variables.

Comment: @bricktop Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38676582/3074564) for details about the commands __SETLOCAL__ and __ENDLOCAL__.

Answer (score 1):

here is a method where you can use delayedexpansion without the use of escape characters.

```
@echo off
setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
set myfile="10 Products You’ll Never Buy Again Knowing How They Are Made!.mp4"
echo %DB_password%
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
echo !myfile!
```

Comment: It would be good to explain what exactly happens on the two lines `setlocal disabledelayedexpansion` and `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` as there is much more done than just disabling/enabling delayed expansion which could result in a stack overflow or other unexpected behavior depending on rest of batch code. See bottom half of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38676582/3074564) on what the commands `setlocal` and `endlocal` always do.

Comment: when this didn't work for me it lead me to the problem I was having. I was calling the namer script within enabled expansion. however I am still having trouble with my scripts, I will continue to debug them.