# Create Batch File

Tags: batch-file

I have this assignment from my teacher in regards to creating a batch file that does something. its pretty huge assignment, but one part i stuck. it asks:
If the value of the userdomain variable is equal to the value of the computername variable then
Store into a file called output.txt the following information:
1.  The current username
2.  The current computername

So im thinking, my username(domain username) would never be same as a computer name anywhere in the world! lol
So that would NEVER happen! in this case i should do nothing!

So im confused. What am i missing?!

Comment: Asking your instructor to clarify the assignment if you're confused.

Comment: I did, she said, reread the assignment! so thats why i paste it here. maybe im reading it wrong!

Comment: Then I suspect you're overthinking the problem, and you're expected to write the code just as described without worrying about whether it could ever happen or not. The point is most likely an exercise in figuring out how to write the code.

Comment: Don't over think it. I answered your question on [DosTips](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=8254) as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to give the computer the name of the user account in a domain. That is not forbidden. That your computer has a different name than your user account in domain or locally does not mean it is not possible.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
:RunNameCompare
if /I "%COMPUTERNAME%" == "%USERNAME%" (
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    echo User name: !USERNAME!>output.txt
    echo Computer name: !COMPUTERNAME!>>output.txt
    endlocal
) else (
    echo/
    echo Computer name and user account name are different.
    echo/
    %SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /N /M "Simulate identical names [Y/N]: "
    if not errorlevel 2 set "COMPUTERNAME=%USERNAME%" & goto RunNameCompare
)
endlocal
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `choice /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

See also the following pages and articles:

- Wikipedia article about [Windows Environment Variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Windows)
- Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx)
- Microsoft article about [Testing for a Specific Error Level in Batch Files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/69576)
- [Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564)
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38676582/3074564) for details about the commands **SETLOCAL** and **ENDLOCAL**
- DosTips forum topic [ECHO. FAILS to give text or blank line - Instead use ECHO/](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=774)

The outer **SETLOCAL** and **ENDLOCAL** are used to create a local environment on running this batch file so that even after taking the *simulate identical names* option, the predefined environment variable `COMPUTERNAME` has its original value after running the batch file from within a command prompt window as recommended on debugging and verifying a batch file in development.

The inner **SETLOCAL** and **ENDLOCAL** are used to be able to output correct into file `output.txt` even computer and user account names containing command line critical characters like `` &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~|<> `` or ending with a space and a number in range `1` to `9` without enclosing both names in double quotes.