# batch xcopy only files that are not present in destination

Tags: windows, batch-file

```
-TheGame/
     - Game files/
             -> file1.whatever
             -> file2.whatever
             -> file3.whatever
     -> Launcher.exe

 -TheGameModed/
     - Game files/
             -> file1.whatever        (the moded file)
     -> Launcher.exe                  (the moded launcher)
```

I made a mod on a game and i want to create an installer for people to play my game.
In order to preventing backup problems (if the player want to revert to vanilla) i will put the mod folder aside the game folder.
The mod folder contain only the "moded files" and in want to make a batch that will copy file from the game folder that are not already present in the destination (even if there are not the same)

Is this right :
`xcopy "../TheGame" "../TheGameModed" /q /s /e`

There is a documentation here but i didn't find what i'm looking for :
https://www.computerhope.com/xcopyhlp.htm

I found only this :

> /U    Copies only files that already exist in destination.
>   But i need the opposite (Copies only files that doesn't exist in destination)

P.S. : When the batch copy files, it ask me if i want to overwrite or not, and since i have only few filesit is not so hard to type n few times. But the mod will be deleted if someone type y (that would be bad) and maybe next mod will contain more files :[

Comment: You should use `/Y : Suppresses prompting to confirm you want to overwrite an existing destination file.`

Comment: `echo N|xcopy "../TheGame" "../TheGameModed" /q /s /e`

Comment: @Hackoo - that will silently overwrite existing files - the exact opposit of what the querent desires.

Comment: It should be noted that `XCOPY` is severely deprecated; you should look into using [`ROBOCOPY`](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html), which has quite different options.

Comment: Squashman, the echo N| skip "pause", how to do keep the "pause" ?

Comment: @MisterAqua, I have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: I mean that in my bat, if the copy ends succesfully, i will have :
- echo Mod installed (new line) -pause

Comment: "pause" will wait for an input from the user.

Comment: @MisterAqua Piping an N to xcopy just answers the overwrite question for you.  I have no idea what this has to do with you putting a pause in your code.  If you have additional code that you do not understand, edit your question with the additional code and clarify what the problem is with the additional code.  Please read the help for comments before you write another comment. Especially the section about notifying people.

Comment: @MisterAqua - check `ROBOCOPY` [***File Selection Options*** examples](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1073.robocopy-and-a-few-examples.aspx#File_Selection_Options)

**ROBOCOPY** *<source> <destination>* ***[file…] [options]***

    robocopy "C:\Source Folder\*.*" "D:\Destination Folder\*.*" /xx

`/xx Excludes extra files that exist in the destination directory`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps **ROBOCOPY** can't be used because the game updating batch file should work also on Windows XP. In this case the following batch file could be perhaps used working on Windows NT4 and all later Windows versions:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
pushd "%~dp0"
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir "TheGame\*" /A-D /B /S 2^>nul') do call :CopyFile "%%I"
popd
endlocal
exit

:CopyFile
set "SourcePath=%~dp1"
set "TargetPath=%SourcePath:\TheGame\=\TheGameModed\%"
if not exist "%TargetPath%%~nx1" %SystemRoot%\System32\xcopy.exe "%~1" "%TargetPath%" /C /I /Q >nul
goto :EOF
```

The batch file first creates a [local environment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38676582/3074564).

Next it pushes path of current directory on stack and sets the directory of the batch file as current directory. It is expected by this batch file being stored in the directory containing the subdirectories `TheGame` and `TheGameModed`.

Then command **DIR** is executed to output

- the names of just all files because of `/A-D` (attribute not directory)
- with name of file only because of `/B` (bare format)
- in specified directory `TheGame` and all subdirectories because of `/S`
- and with full path also because of `/S`.

This **DIR** command line is executed in a separate command process started by **FOR** in background with `cmd.exe /C` which captures everything written by this command process respectively by **DIR** to handle **STDOUT**.

Read the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes **DIR** command line with using a separate command process started in background.

The **FOR** option `delims=` disables the standard behavior of splitting up each non empty line not starting with a semicolon into strings using space/tab as delimiter. In other words each file name with file extension and full path is assigned to loop variable `I`.

The name of each file with file extension and full path is passed to a subroutine called `CopyFile`.

The subroutine first assigns just path of source file found in `TheGame` directory tree to environment variable `SourcePath`. Next a string substitution is used to replace in this path `TheGame` by `TheGameModed` with including the directory separators on both side for more accuracy.

After having target path for current file in `TheGame` directory tree it is checked next if a file with that name in that path exists already in `TheGameModed` directory tree.

If the file does not exist, command **XCOPY** is used to copy this single file to `TheGameModed` with automatically creating the entire directory tree if that is necessary. This directory creation feature of **XCOPY** is the main reason for using **XCOPY** instead of **COPY**.

After processing all files in `TheGame` directory tree, the initial current directory is restored from stack as well as the initial environment before exiting current command process independent on calling hierarchy and how the command process was started initially.

The commands **POPD** and **ENDLOCAL** would not be really necessary with `exit` being the next line. I recommend usually to use `exit /B` or `goto :EOF` instead of **EXIT**, but [goto :EOF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37518000/3074564) fails if command extensions are not enabled and we can't be 100% sure that the command extensions are enabled on starting the batch file although by default command extensions are enabled on Windows.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `exit /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `popd /?`
- `pushd /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `xcopy /?`