# batch files calling %~1 and getting the variable's current value/string

Tags: batch-file

The code below is related to batch files (command prompt). My problem is the part of the code that says `current value is %~1` doesn't actually display the value of `%~1` (I would like it to say string01 or string02) am not too sure how to do this. I have looked around but cannot wrap my head around this simple problem.

```
@echo off 
goto :MainFunction 

:Func01 
echo. 
echo Running Func01 
echo Variable %~1 current value is %~1 
echo. 
echo Set new value for Variable %~1: 
set /p %~1= 
goto :eof 

:MainFunction 
echo This is the main function! 
set Var01=string01 
set var02=string02 
echo Var01 is equal to %Var01% 
echo Var02 is equal to %Var02% 
call :Func01 Var01 
call :Func01 Var02 
echo Var01 is now equal to %Var01% 
echo Var02 is now equal to %Var02% 
goto :eof
```

Comment: try with `call :Func01 "%Var01%"`

Comment: hi npocmaka, I tired that but that gives "Variable string01 current value is string01" which is a problem because I need it to say "Variable Var01 current value is string01".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another method is using command **CALL** to get a double parsing of a command line as shown below:

```
@echo off
goto :MainFunction

:Func01
echo/
echo Running Func01
call echo Variable %~1 current value is %%%~1%%
echo/
set /P "%~1=Set new value for Variable %~1: "
goto :EOF

:MainFunction
echo This is the main function!
set "Var01=string01"
set "var02=string02"
echo Var01 is equal to %Var01%
echo Var02 is equal to %Var02%
call :Func01 Var01
call :Func01 Var02
echo Var01 is now equal to %Var01%
echo Var02 is now equal to %Var02%
goto :EOF
```

The command line

```
call echo Variable %~1 current value is %%%~1%%
```

is first modified before running **CALL** by Windows command interpreter for example on first execution of subroutine `Func01` to

```
call echo Variable Var01 current value is %Var01%
```

On parsing this command line a second time on running **CALL** the command line changes to:

```
echo Variable Var01 current value is string01
```

The character `%` must be escaped with one more `%` to be interpreted as literal character in a batch file which is the reason for the strange looking syntax `%%%~1%%`.

And take a look on DosTips forum topic [ECHO. FAILS to give text or blank line - Instead use ECHO/](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=774) for the explanation on using `echo/` instead of `echo.` to output an empty line.

Answer (score 3):

You want to get both the variable name and the value in a single parameter?

In the line `echo Variable %~1 current value is %~1` , the second `%~1` has to evaluated. Sou need another layer of parsing. The "usual" way to do so, is to use [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082):

```
@echo off 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
goto :MainFunction 

:Func01 
echo. 
echo Running Func01 
echo Variable %~1 current value is !%~1! 
echo. 
echo Set new value for Variable %~1: 
set /p %~1= 
goto :eof 

:MainFunction 
echo This is the main function! 
set Var01=string01 
set var02=string02 
echo Var01 is equal to %Var01% 
echo Var02 is equal to %Var02% 
call :Func01 Var01 
call :Func01 Var02 
echo Var01 is now equal to %Var01% 
echo Var02 is now equal to %Var02% 
goto :eof
```

Comment: thanks Stephan seemed to do the trick. going to go research about "setlocal enabledelayedexpansion"

Comment: @JimmyWilliams The help of command __SET__ output on running in a command prompt window `set /?` explains usage of delayed environment variable expansion on an __IF__ and a __FOR__ example. See also [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html). But please note that with delayed environment variable expansion being enabled a not escaped exclamation mark `!` is interpreted not anymore as literal character in a command line, but as begin/end of an environment variable reference. For that reason `!` in line `echo This is the main function!` is not output anymore. `^^!` is needed.

Comment: @JimmyWilliams For help on commands __SETLOCAL__ and __ENDLOCAL__ run in a command prompt window `setlocal /?` and `endlocal /?` and read additionally second half of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38676582/3074564) for details about those two commands.