# the system cannot find the path specified when running batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to move files after sorting the files from one folder to another folder but I am always getting this exception **"The System cannot find the path specified"**

Below is my batch command code:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set destinationFolder=C:\Test_Actual_Queue
rem Create an array with filenames in right order
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /b "C:\Test Print Queue\" ^| sort') do (
 echo %%f
 move %%f %destinationFolder%
)
pause
```

I am able to sort and display the file names in console but when I try to move to the destination folder , I am getting the above mentioned exception.

Both the folder paths are correct.

I tried debugging and this is the data I am getting in the console:

```
C:\TestFoder>setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

C:\TestFoder>set destinationFolder=C:\Test_Actual_Queue

C:\TestFoder>rem Create an array with filenames in right order

C:\TestFoder>for /F "tokens=*" %f in ('dir /b "C:\Test Print Queue\" | sort') do (
echo %f
 move %f C:\Test_Actual_Queue
)

C:\TestFoder>(
echo data1.Print_Job
 move data1.Print_Job C:\Test_Actual_Queue
)
data1.Print_Job
The system cannot find the file specified.

C:\TestFoder>(
echo data2.Print_Job
 move data2.Print_Job C:\Test_Actual_Queue
)
data2.Print_Job
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

what am I doing wrong here?

Looking forward to your solutions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because the for variable only outputs the file name and not the folder.  The working directory of your batch file is different so it is trying to find the file in the current working directory.  You need to include the input folder path with the move command.

Comment: Can i get the path of sorted file in for loop?

Comment: You know what the input folder path is.  You have it in your DIR command!

Comment: Yes.. I got it.. I have done a concatenation of path like : C:\Test Print Queue\%%f inside the for loop and now its working,, Thanks Squashman for the input..

Comment: Change `'dir /b "C:\Test Print Queue\" ^| sort'` to `'Dir /B/ON "C:\Test Print Queue"'`; there's no need to use the external `sort.exe`, when `Dir` can output sorted already.

Comment: @Compo correct. Comment deleted.

Comment: It may have been worth using either `PushD` or `CD` to work from `"C:\Test Print Queue"` first, then just use `'Dir /B/ON'` inside the parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command **DIR** with the arguments `/b` and `"C:\Test Print Queue\"` outputs just the names of all non hidden files and directories in specified directory without path. The current directory on execution of the batch file is `C:\TestFoder` which is a different directory than `C:\Test Print Queue`. For that reason the command **MOVE** cannot find the file/directory to move stored in `C:\Test Print Queue` specified without path in current directory `C:\TestFoder` and outputs the error message.

The command **DIR** would output the file/folder names with full path if additionally option `/S` is used to search also in subdirectories.

One solution is specifying source path also on **MOVE** command line:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set "SourceFolder=C:\Test Print Queue"
set "DestinationFolder=C:\Test_Actual_Queue"
set "CreatedFolder="

if not exist "%DestinationFolder%\" (
    md "%DestinationFolder%" 2>nul
    if not exist "%DestinationFolder%\" (
        echo Error: Failed to create folder "%DestinationFolder%"
        goto EndBatch
    )
    set "CreatedFolder=1"
)

for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir /A-D-H /B /ON "%SourceFolder%\*" 2^>nul') do (
    echo Moving file "%SourceFolder%\%%I" ...
    move "%SourceFolder%\%%I" "%DestinationFolder%\"
)

if defined CreatedFolder rd "%DestinationFolder%" 2>nul

:EndBatch
endlocal
pause
```

Command extensions are explicitly enabled as required for `for /F` although enabled by default. Delayed environment variable expansion is explicitly disabled as not needed for this task. Files with one or more exclamation marks in file name could not be successfully processed within the **FOR** loop if delayed environment variable expansion is enabled explicitly although not enabled by default and not needed here. Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38676582/3074564) for details about the commands **SETLOCAL** and **ENDLOCAL**.

The batch file first creates the destination folder if not already existing with verifying if folder creation was successful.

The command **FOR** executes the command line

```
dir /A-D-H /B /ON "C:\Test Print Queue\*" 2>nul
```

in a background command process started with `cmd.exe /C`.

Command **DIR** outputs

- just **non hidden files** because of `/A-D-H` which means all directory entries **not** having attribute directory or hidden set
- in bare format because of `/B` which means **just the file name with file extension** and without file path
- **sorted by name** because of `/ON`
- found in directory `C:\Test Print Queue` matching the wildcard pattern `*` (any file).

It is possible that the source directory does not exist at all or does not contain any file matching the criteria. The error message output in these cases by **DIR** is suppressed by redirecting it from handle **STDERR** to device **NUL**.

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `dir` command line with using a separate command process started in background.

**FOR** with option `/F` as used here captures everything written to handle **STDOUT** of background command process and then processes the captured text line by line.

Empty lines are ignored by **FOR**, but **DIR** with the used options does not output empty lines at all.

Lines starting with `;` would be also ignored by default by **FOR**. File names can start with a semicolon. For that reason option `eol=|` is used to change the end of line character from semicolon (default) to a vertical bar which a file name can't contain at all.

**FOR** would split up each line into substrings (tokens) using the default delimiters space and horizontal tab and would assign to loop variable `I` just the first space/tab delimited string. This splitting behavior is not wanted here and so option `delims=` is used to define an empty list of delimiters to disable the line splitting and get assigned to `I` always the entire file name even on containing one or more spaces. `tokens=*` could be also used to get entire line (= file name) assigned to `I`.

For each file output by **DIR** with name and extension, but without path, the name of the file is output and command **MOVE** is executed to move the file to destination folder without overwriting a file with same name in that folder because of option `/Y` is not used here.

Finally the batch file deletes the destination folder if it was created by the batch file and if it is still empty because there was no file to move at all.

Another solution would be changing the current directory to source directory.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
cd /D "C:\Test Print Queue" || goto EndBatch

set "DestinationFolder=C:\Test_Actual_Queue"
set "CreatedFolder="

if not exist "%DestinationFolder%\" (
    md "%DestinationFolder%" 2>nul
    if not exist "%DestinationFolder%\" (
        echo Error: Failed to create folder "%DestinationFolder%"
        goto EndBatch
    )
    set "CreatedFolder=1"
)

for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir /A-D-H /B /ON 2^>nul') do (
    echo Moving file "%%I" ...
    move "%%I" "%DestinationFolder%\"
)

if defined CreatedFolder rd "%DestinationFolder%" 2>nul

:EndBatch
endlocal
pause
```

If command **CD** fails to change the current directory to source directory because of not existing, the well known error message is output:

> The system cannot find the path specified.

Then the batch file jumps to the label `EndBatch` to restore previous environment and halt batch file execution until user presses any key.

On successfully changing the current directory the batch file continues and with command **ENDLOCAL** the initial current directory `C:\TestFoder` is set again as current directory for the command process executing the batch file.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `cd /?`
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `md /?`
- `move /?`
- `pause /?`
- `rd /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`