# Returning string from external function batch

Tags: windows, function, batch-file

I have two batch files. One is the main (caller) file and one is a function.
The function takes one parameter, does some stuff and then i wanna return the string to the caller (main.bat). %ERRORLEVEL% is not an option, as it can only return integers.

main.bat:
`call function.bat hello`
function.bat:
`REM some code.......`
[HERE THE CODE TO RETURN A STRING TO CALLER FILE]
Seems like a basic operation, so there must be a way. Also, i prefer not making files with the output and reading it in the main.bat, because i want to make it work as a easy-to-use function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The two batch files are executed both by same Windows command processor process and share therefore all environment variables.

**Main.bat:**

```
@echo off
set "MyVariable="
call Function.bat hello
echo MyVariable=%MyVariable%
```

**Function.bat:**

```
@echo off
rem Some code ...
set "MyVariable=%~1"
```

It could be that `Function.bat` uses for some reason command **SETLOCAL**. In this case all environment variables defined as well as all modifications made on environment variables after the command **SETLOCAL** are lost after corresponding **ENDLOCAL**. This command is implicitly called by Windows command processor on exiting execution of a batch file for each **SETLOCAL** not yet completed with explicit execution of corresponding **ENDLOCAL**. Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38676582/3074564) for details about the commands **SETLOCAL** and **ENDLOCAL**.

It is necessary to explicitly set an environment variable on same command line as the command **ENDLOCAL** with using immediate environment variable expansion to pass value of an environment variable from current environment variables list to previous environment variables list.

**Function.bat:**

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
rem Some code ...
set "MyVariable=%~1"
endlocal & set "MyVariable=%MyVariable%"
```

The last command line is preprocessed first by Windows command interpreter to

```
endlocal   & set "MyVariable=hello"
```

So the command line after preprocessing does not contain anymore any variable reference. The command **ENDLOCAL** restores previous environment which results in deletion of environment variable `MyVariable`. But the second command **SET** specified on same command line sets this variable once again with the value `hello` in restored environment.

See also [Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25343351/).