# batch script echo dynamic variable

Tags: batch-file

I have a dynamic variable in my batch script and I need to use it or print it later on in the script, for example

```
set txt1=hello world
echo %txt1%
set /a num=1
echo %txt%%num%
```

In the second line in this sample, the result will be "hello world", but in the last line it will be 1, how can I make the last line to print "hello world" using a dynamic variable

Comment: I'd wager that you'd get more than a few hits using this search term, **[batch-file]dynamic variable**; [take a look](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5Ddynamic+variable).

Comment: Mmmm... This is not a _dynamic variable_, but an _array element_, that is, there are several `txt` elements that are selected via a numeric _index_ or _subscript_. For details on array management in Batch files see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990). PS: in Batch files the _dynamic variables_ are `time`, `random`, etc. Enter `set /?` and read the part about _"environment dynamic variables"_...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use an arithmetic expression to assign a number string to an environment variable. That is in most cases useless although always working. So use `set "num=1"` instead of `set /a num=1`. For the reason read answer on [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564)

It is necessary to get the last command line parsed twice by `cmd.exe` which can be reached by either using delayed expansion or using command **CALL** as explained in detail by answer on [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/)

The solution using command **CALL**:

```
set "txt1=hello world"
echo %txt1%
set "num=1"
call echo %%txt%num%%%
```

The last line is first processed to `call echo %txt1%` and next processed a second time because of command **CALL** to `echo hello world` which is finally executed by `cmd.exe`.

The second solution using [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html):

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "txt1=hello world"
echo %txt1%
set "num=1"
echo !txt%num%!
endlocal
```

The last but one line is first processed to `echo !txt1!` which is processed a second time because of delayed environment variable expansion to `echo hello world` on execution of the batch file.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38676582/3074564) for details about the commands **SETLOCAL** and **ENDLOCAL**.

Comment: Many thanks for this explanation, actually the command `echo !txt%num%!` is exactly what I am looking for