# Copy *d.dll into debug folder and *.dll without *d.dll into release

Tags: batch-file

I have a library with files like

```
opencv_dnn340.dll
opencv_dnn340d.dll
opencv_features2d340.dll
opencv_features2d340d.dll
opencv_ffmpeg340_64.dll
opencv_flann340.dll
opencv_flann340d.dll
opencv_highgui340.dll
opencv_highgui340d.dll
opencv_imgcodecs340.dll
opencv_imgcodecs340d.dll
opencv_imgproc340.dll
opencv_imgproc340d.dll
```

I am trying to copy only the *d.dll files in debug mode 
and copy all of the *.dll files without *d.dll in release mode

I started with this

```
if %ConfigurationName% == Debug xcopy /y /d "%SolutionDir%..\..\ia-imaging-opencv-libs\3.4.0\windows\x64\vc12\bin\*d.dll" "%TargetDir%\"

else xcopy /y /d "%SolutionDir%..\..\ia-imaging-opencv-libs\3.4.0\windows\x64\vc12\bin\*.dll" "%TargetDir%\"
```

but in release I copy all of the files.

now I am trying to use for loop

```
for /R "%SolutionDir%..\..\ia-imaging-opencv-libs\3.4.0\windows\x64\vc12\bin\" "%%File" IN *.dll
    if %ConfigurationName% == Debug & findstr /R *d.dll "%%File"
       xcopy /y /d "%%File" "%TargetDir%\"
    else %ConfigurationName% == Release & NEQ findstr /R *d.dll "%%File"
       xcopy /y /d "%%File" "%TargetDir%\"
```

Can you please help with how to create a copy for *.dll file without the *d.dll files thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I created 3 folders, Libs, Debug and Release. Libs folder contains

```
opencv_dnn340.dll
opencv_dnn340d.dll
opencv_features2d340.dll
opencv_features2d340d.dll
```

Using Robocopy
Move to Debug

```
robocopy Libs Debug *d.dll
```

Move to Release

```
robocopy Libs Release /XF *d.dll
```

Comment: if %ConfigurationName% == Debug robocopy %SolutionDir%..\..\ia-imaging-opencv-libs\3.4.0\windows\x64\vc12\bin\" "%TargetDir%\" *d.dll
if %ConfigurationName% == Release robocopy %SolutionDir%..\..\ia-imaging-opencv-libs\3.4.0\windows\x64\vc12\bin\" "%TargetDir%\" /XF *d.dll this doesn't work

Comment: Could you send the error message? I think something wrong with " happened. The corrected statement might be the -> if %ConfigurationName% == Debug robocopy "%SolutionDir%..\..\ia-imaging-opencv-libs\3.4.0\windows\x64\vc12\bin\" "%TargetDir%\" *d.dll if %ConfigurationName% == Release robocopy "%SolutionDir%..\..\ia-imaging-opencv-libs\3.4.0\windows\x64\vc12\bin\" "%TargetDir%\" /XF *d.dll

Comment: >EXEC : error : Invalid Parameter #2 : "G:\Git\IQS\iqs-trunk\ia-tools-iqstudio\iqstudio\Export\Debug" *d.dll"

Comment: ok fixed it if %ConfigurationName% == Debug robocopy %SolutionDir%..\..\ia-imaging-opencv-libs\3.4.0\windows\x64\vc12\bin\ %TargetDir%\ *d.dll
if %ConfigurationName% == Release robocopy %SolutionDir%..\..\ia-imaging-opencv-libs\3.4.0\windows\x64\vc12\bin\ %TargetDir%\ /XF *d.dll

Answer (score 0):

Just provide a thought, so you need not to use complicated mechanism:

```
mkdir _tmp_nod_
mkdir _tmp_d_
copy /y /d sourceDir\*.dll _tmp_nod_\
move /y _tmp_nod_\*d.dll _tmp_d_\
IF %ConfigurationName% == Debug (move _tmp_d_\* "%TargetDir%\") ELSE (move _tmp_nod_\* "%TargetDir%\")
:: rd /s /q _tmp_nod_
:: rd /s /q _tmp_d_
```

Which is, copy all those dlls to a temporary folder, and move those `*d.dll` files out to another temporary folder, than the former folder will only have those `*.dll`s without `d`, And later you can choose one temporary folder to copy depend on the condition.

However, another way could be list `*d.dll` first and save the list to a `txt` file (use `dir /b` maybe), and later when `xcopy *.dll` use that `txt` file as the parameter of `/EXCLUDE:`. This could also acheive the excluding.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more solution for this file copying task:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
if /I "%ConfigurationName%" == "Debug" ( set "FilterOption=" ) else set "FilterOption=/V"
for %%I in ("%SolutionDir%\..\..\ia-imaging-opencv-libs\3.4.0\windows\x64\vc12\bin") do set "DllFolder=%%~fI"
for /F "delims= eol=" %%I in ('dir "%DllFolder%\*.dll" /A-D-H /B 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /E /I /L %FilterOption% "d.dll"') do %SystemRoot%\System32\xcopy.exe "%DllFolder%\%%I" "%TargetDir%\" /C /D /Q /R /Y >nul
endlocal
```

The environment variable `FilterOption` is deleted respectively not defined if environment variable `ConfigurationName` is defined and its string value is case-insensitive equal the string `Debug`. In all other cases the environment variable `FilterOption` is defined in local environment setup with `setlocal` and `endlocal` with the option value string `/V`. Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38676582/3074564) for details about the commands **SETLOCAL** and **ENDLOCAL**.

The fourth line with first `for` just determines full qualified absolute path of the folder containing the dynamic linked library files without the relative path parts which is assigned to environment variable `DllFolder`.

The fifth line with second `for` makes the real job. **FOR** executes in a separate command process started with `cmd.exe /C` (more precise with `%CompSpec% /C`) in background the command line:

```
dir "%DllFolder%\*.dll" /A-D-H /B 2>nul | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /E /I /L %FilterOption% "d.dll"
```

The environment variable references are already expanded in real on execution.

**DIR** outputs

- just the names of all non-hidden files because of option `/A-D-H` (attribute not directory and not hidden)
- in bare format because of option `/B`
- matching the wildcard pattern `*.dll`
- in the specified directory.

The output file names are without file path, just file name and file extension.

It is possible that **DIR** finds nothing matching these criteria. In this case an error message is output by **DIR** to handle **STDOUT** which is suppressed by redirecting it with `2>nul` to device **NUL**.

The output of **DIR** is redirected with `|` to **STDIN** of **FINDSTR** which searches

- at end of every line because of option `/E`
- case-insensitive because of option `/I`
- and interpreting the search string as literal string because of option `/L`
- for the string `d.dll`

and outputs to handle **STDOUT** of background command process all lines ending with `d.dll` on `FilterOption` not defined or the inverse result on `FilterOption` defined with value `/V`, i.e. all lines **not** ending with `d.dll`.

Read the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul` and `|`. The redirection operators `>` and `|` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal characters when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `dir` command line with `findstr` with using a separate command process started in background.

**FOR** captures everything output to handle **STDOUT** of started background command process and processes this output line by line after started command process terminated itself.

**FOR** with option `/F` ignores empty lines which do not occur here. **FOR** would also ignore lines (= file names) starting with a semicolon which most likely do not occur here. But the end of line option is redefined with `eol=` to define no character as end of line option which disables this **FOR** filter. **FOR** would also split up every line into substrings using normal space and horizontal tab as delimiters and would assign only first space/tab separated string to loop variable `I`. There are most likely no library files with a space in file name, but with `delims=` this line splitting behavior is disabled by defining no character as delimiter.

So **FOR** executes for every file name output by **DIR** passing **FINDSTR** filter the command **XCOPY** to copy the file to the target directory if the source file does not already exist in target directory with a newer last modification date whereby **XCOPY** automatically creates also the entire directory structure to target directory if that is necessary on target directory not yet existing.

It would be also possible to use **COPY** instead of **XCOPY**. But in this case there should be the command line `md "%TargetDir%" 2>nul` somewhere above second **FOR** command line to make sure the target directory exists because of **COPY** does not create automatically the directory tree to the target directory.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `xcopy /?`

Answer (score -1):

I guess you could use option `/exclude:exclude_file.txt` for that.
So if you put your pattern there `d.dll` and add this option to your release xcopy `xcopy /exclude:debug_dlls_pattern.txt` you'll get copied only release dll.