# How to show what user typed in this command?

Tags: batch-file, variables

please help! I was looking for the answer all over the internet.

Here's my code:

```
@echo off
title var test
:question
set a1=This
set a2=Is
set a3=a
set a4=Var
set a5=Test
choice /c 12345 /m "press a number"
if errorlevel=5 set num=5&goto answer
if errorlevel=4 set num=4&goto answer
if errorlevel=3 set num=3&goto answer
if errorlevel=2 set num=2&goto answer
if errorlevel=1 set num=1&goto answer
:answer
echo now change the answer.
set /p a%num%=
FOR /F "tokens=1-6" %%1 IN ("%a1% %a2% %a3% %a4% %a5% a%num%") DO echo %%1 %%2 %%4 %%5.&echo You typed=%%6
pause
goto question
```

As you can see I made the user select a number between 1 and 5 to change the specific word. But when I try same kind of code to show what he typed doesn't work :(

Comment: For loops use %%<letter> not number.

Comment: I know, but numbers from 1 to 9 works as well.

Comment: no, don't use numbers, these are assigned by default to input variables `%1`... anyway,  your real problem is with the `if errorlevel` statements. try rather `if errorlevel 5 set..` by losing the = sign. Or even using `%errorlevel%` as `if "%errorlevel%"=="5" do...` you also have numerous other issues here and honestly do not even need thefor loop.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard, the `=` in this `if` statements is nothing but a standard token separator (just like the space), just to be precise... ;-) Anyway, `if ErrorLevel 1` actually means *if ErrorLevel is **greater than or equal to** 1* (type `if /?`), so these `if` statements needed to be put in reverse order. After the `if` statements, an error case should also be catched (like `goto question`, for instance, because `choice` returns an `ErrorLevel` of `0` if Ctrl+C is pressed, which would currently cause the `:answer` section to be executed)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Environment variables should never begin with a digit and using a digits for loop variables should be also avoided. Run in a command prompt window `call /?` and output is the help for this command explaining how batch file arguments can be referenced with `%0`, `%1`, `%2`, ... which explains why environment variables with digit as first character and loop variables with a digit are not good in general even on being 
`a%num%` in set of **FOR** does not reference the value of environment variable `a1` or `a2` or `a3` or `a4` or `a5`. It is just the name of the environment variable. The `for` loop is not necessary at all.

```
@echo off
title var test
:question
set "a1=This"
set "a2=Is"
set "a3=a"
set "a4=Var"
set "a5=Test"
%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /C 12345E /N /M "Press a number in range 1-5 or E for exit: "
if errorlevel 6 goto :EOF
set "num=%ERRORLEVEL%"
set /P "a%num%=Now change the answer: "
echo %a1% %a2% %a3% %a4% %a5%.
call echo You typed: %%a%num%%%
pause
goto question
```

The command line `call echo You typed: %%a%num%%%` is parsed by Windows command processor before execution of the command line on number `3` entered to `call echo You typed: %a3%`. This command line is parsed a second time because of command `call` resulting in replacing `%a3%` by the value of environment variable `a3` and so `echo` outputs the expected string.

It would be also possible to replace `call echo You typed: %%a%num%%%` by

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo You typed: !a%num%!
endlocal
```

The usage of delayed environment variable expansion results also in double parsing the command line before execution of command `echo`. For more details see [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/)

Please read also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38676582/3074564) for details about the commands **SETLOCAL** and **ENDLOCAL**.

The two lines below in batch code above are also not really good taking into account that the user can really enter anything.

```
echo %a1% %a2% %a3% %a4% %a5%.
call echo You typed: %%a%num%%%
```

For example if the user enters number `1` and on next prompt enters:

```
Your user name is:& setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion & echo !UserName!& endlocal & rem
```

Then the batch file does something completely different than designed for and outputs the user's account name.

Secure would be the batch code:

```
@echo off
title var test
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
:question
set "a1=This"
set "a2=Is"
set "a3=a"
set "a4=Var"
set "a5=Test"
%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /C 12345E /N /M "Press a number in range 1-5 or E for exit: "
if errorlevel 6 goto :EOF
set "num=%ERRORLEVEL%"
set /P "a%num%=Now change the answer: "
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo !a1! !a2! !a3! !a4! !a5!.
echo You typed: !a%num%!
endlocal
pause
goto question
```

Now the user input string cannot modify anymore the command lines executed by Windows command processor.

A solution with the useless **FOR** loop would be:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F tokens^=1-6^ eol^= %%A in ("!a1! !a2! !a3! !a4! !a5! !a%num%!") do echo %%A %%B %%C %%D %%E.&echo You typed: %%F
endlocal
```

`eol=` is necessary to output everything correct also if use enters number `1` and next a string starting with a semicolon. The **FOR** options string cannot be enclosed in double quotes in this case like `"tokens=1-6 eol="` because of this would define `"` as end of line character and nothing is output if user enters number `1` and enters next a string starting with `"`. The equal sign and the space must be escaped with `^` to be interpreted as literal characters by `cmd.exe` on double parsing the entire `for` command line before execution of command `for`.

Note: The **FOR** loop solution does not work correct on user enters for first variable value the special command line string as posted above. So it is also not really secure.