# Using CMDER, issue with setting PATH

Tags: batch-file, conemu, cmder

I'm trying to use [CMDER](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder) for a development environment that I've setup.

Basically I've created a .bat file that calls:

```
@ECHO OFF 
start Z:\_DEV\OS_WINDOWS\9_MISC_TOOLS\CMDER\Cmder.exe
```

Then I've placed the file [startdev.bat](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ZacWolf/0397b698df227150b30c44847241532e/raw/60a83da9b56aca5ea9cad9d0aa45d32aa7dfc3c3/startdev.bat) in:
%CMDER_HOME%\config\profile.d

So everything seems to work just fine, but when the startdev.bat finishes, issuing an:

```
echo %PATH%
```

returns:

```
Z:\_DEV\OS_WINDOWS\1_COMPILER\JDK\ORACLE\1.8.0_181\bin;Z:\_DEV\OS_CYGWIN\bin;Z:\_DEV\OS_WINDOWS\9_MISC_TOOLS\CLutils;Z:\_DEV\OS_WINDOWS\9_MISC_TOOLS\PUTTY;Z:\_DEV\OS_WINDOWS\6_VERSION_CONTROL\PortableGit\bin;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64;C:\WINDOWS\System32
```

...any idea what's happening?

I would either expect CMDER to override PATH with the value from its own settings, or use my full path, which before the startdev.bat ends shows the value of:

```
PATH=Z:\_DEV\OS_WINDOWS\9_MISC_TOOLS\CMDER\vendor\conemu-maximus5;Z:\_DEV\OS_WINDOWS\9_MISC_TOOLS\CMDER\vendor\conemu-maximus5\ConEmu;Z:\_DEV\OS_WINDOWS\9_MISC_TOOLS\CMDER\vendor\conemu-maximus5\ConEmu\Scripts;Z:\_DEV\OS_ALL\JVM\3_BUILD_TOOLS\GRADLE\5.4\bin;Z:\_DEV\OS_ALL\JVM\3_BUILD_TOOLS\MAVEN\3.5.4\bin;Z:\_DEV\OS_ALL\JVM\3_BUILD_TOOLS\ANT\1.10.5\bin;Z:\_DEV\OS_WINDOWS\3_BUILD_TOOLS\NODE\LTS\10.15.3;Z:\_DEV\OS_WINDOWS\3_BUILD_TOOLS\NODE\LTS\10.15.3\node_modules;Z:\_DEV\OS_WINDOWS\1_COMPILER\GO\1.12.4\bin;Z:\_DEV\OS_WINDOWS\1_COMPILER\PYTHON\32bit\2.7.13;Z:\_DEV\OS_WINDOWS\1_COMPILER\PYTHON\32bit\2.7.13\scripts;Z:\_DEV\OS_WINDOWS\1_COMPILER\ANDROID\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools;Z:\_DEV\OS_WINDOWS\1_COMPILER\JDK\ORACLE\1.8.0_181\bin;Z:\_DEV\OS_CYGWIN\bin;Z:\_DEV\OS_WINDOWS\9_MISC_TOOLS\CLutils;Z:\_DEV\OS_WINDOWS\9_MISC_TOOLS\PUTTY;Z:\_DEV\OS_WINDOWS\6_VERSION_CONTROL\PortableGit\bin;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64;C:\WINDOWS\System32
```

..but the fact that it only seems to be keeping the value as defined about halfway through the batch job is strange.

Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps it's about system and user environment. I don't understand why cmder needs magic with profile.d, all environment you may set up natively in ConEmu settings.

Comment: As @Maximus said, the value of `%PATH%` is the joined contents from both the user and machine environments. You appear to have overwritten only the content of one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I recommend opening a command prompt window and run `setlocal /?` and `endlocal /?` to get displayed the help/documentation for those two commands. Very important to know is that every `setlocal` without a corresponding `endlocal` results in an implicit execution of `endlocal` by `cmd.exe` before exiting processing of a batch file or a subroutine called with command **CALL**.

Next I suggest reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38676582/3074564) for even more details about the commands **SETLOCAL** and **ENDLOCAL** and what happens on using them.

I suggest like [michael_heath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55755803/3074564) to change this code block:

```
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set CLASSPATH=.
for /R %JRE_HOME%\lib %%a in (*.jar) do (
    set CLASSPATH=!CLASSPATH!;%%a
)
set CLASSPATH=!CLASSPATH!
```

Better would be:

```
setLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set CLASSPATH=.
for /R "%JRE_HOME%\lib" %%a in (*.jar) do set "CLASSPATH=!CLASSPATH!;%%a"
endlocal & set "CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%"
```

Now the local environment is ended with passing the environment variable `CLASSPATH` from local environment, on which it was defined, to the restored previous environment because of `cmd.exe` expands `%CLASSPATH%` to current value of the environment variable `CLASSPATH` in current local environment before executing the command `endlocal` which restores the previous environment.

Wrong in your batch file is also `set WINDIR=%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%` which should be `set "WINDIR=%SystemRoot%"`.

I recommend further reading [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564) It explains why the syntax `set "variable=string value"` is recommended nowadays. Many of the environment variable definitions use directly or indirectly `%UserProfile%` which means depending on whatever the user currently running the batch file has entered as user name on creation of the user account. I have seen users entering their name containing a space and non ASCII characters. And I have seen users creating an account with a user name containing character `&` like `Company GmbH & Co`. An ampersand outside a double quoted argument string is interpreted as **AND** operator and `cmd.exe` tries to execute after `set` also the remaining string after `&` as command line on using something like `set USERHOME=%DEVHOME%\%USERNAME%` instead of `set "USERHOME=%DEVHOME%\%USERNAME%"`. Well, `startdev.bat` redefines nearly all predefined [Windows Environment Variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Windows) including `USERNAME` and `USERPROFILE` and so is written safe for most environment variable definitions.

This code block is also not optimal:

```
FOR /F "usebackq" %%i IN (`hostname`) DO SET HOSTNAME=%%i
echo Running on hostname: %HOSTNAME%
```

The host name respectively computer name could contain also a space or characters critical for command line or start with a semicolon for some unknown reason. So better would be:

```
FOR /F delims^=^ eol^= %%i IN ('hostname') DO SET "HOSTNAME=%%i"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion & echo Running on host name: !HOSTNAME!& endlocal
```

Whereby there is the environment variable `COMPUTERNAME` predefined by Windows making it possible to use just following command line:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion & echo Running on host name: !ComputerName!& endlocal
```

An **ECHO** command line containing an immediately expanded environment variable reference on which it is unknown if its value contains `&|<>` is always a problem because of the environment variable reference is expanded before further processing of the command line by `cmd.exe` as described at [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/)

I suggest also reading DosTips forum topic [ECHO. FAILS to give text or blank line - Instead use ECHO/](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=774) and avoid the usage of `echo.` in the batch file to output an empty line.

Answer (score 0):

"*halfway through the batch job*" as you have a
`setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion` which sets any further
changes to the variable `PATH` or other set variables as *local*.
The `endLocal` not specified is implied at the end of the script.

To resolve this, use `endLocal` and `set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%`
on the same parsed line to set `CLASSPATH` as *global*.

Change this part:

```
    setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set CLASSPATH=.
    for /R %JRE_HOME%\lib %%a in (*.jar) do (
        set CLASSPATH=!CLASSPATH!;%%a
    )
    set CLASSPATH=!CLASSPATH!
```

to this:

```
    setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set CLASSPATH=.
    for /R %JRE_HOME%\lib %%a in (*.jar) do (
        set CLASSPATH=!CLASSPATH!;%%a
    )
    endLocal & set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%
```

After that changed part, the script will `set` variables as *global* again.

Comment: Thanks so much for this! Excellent information, but since @Mofi goes into a bit more detail I awarded him the answer. But thanks for the answer!!!