# Echo directory opened by shell:startup

Tags: windows, command-prompt, special-folders

When entering `start shell:startup` into the command prompt, it opens a new window at the startup folder. How can I print the path to that folder but not actually open the folder in explorer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [.NET's `Environment.SpecialFolder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=netframework-4.8). This PowerShell command will give you the path of startup folder

```powershell
[Environment]::GetFolderPath([Environment+SpecialFolder]::Startup)
```

---

If you really want to use cmd then you can call the above command like this

```bat
powershell -C [Environment]::GetFolderPath([Environment+SpecialFolder]::Startup)
```

and use use [`for /f`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6359820/995714) to save that to a variable like normal

Alternatively use a hybrid Batch/VBS solution

```vb
<!-- : Begin batch script
@echo off
cscript //nologo "%~f0?.wsf" %1
exit /b

----- Begin wsf script --->
<job><script language="VBScript">

Set oShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set oSFolders = oShell.SpecialFolders
WScript.Echo oSFolders("Startup")

</script></job>
```

or hybrid Batch/Js

```js
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then
@echo off
cscript //e:jscript //nologo "%~f0" %*
exit /b
@end

// JScript Section
WScript.Echo((new ActiveXObject("shell.application")).namespace(0x07).Self.Path);
```

0x07 here is the [*Shell Special Folder Constant* for startup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shldisp/ne-shldisp-shellspecialfolderconstants)

Just save the above 2 snippets as a *.bat file and run. Or strip the batch part and make it a pure VBS/Js solution.

In fact these snippets use COM objects so they can be written in any languages that support COM objects, for example in PowerShell:

```
(New-Object –ComObject Shell.Application).namespace(0x07).Self.Path
```

or

```
$c = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
$c.SpecialFolders("Startup")
```

---

It's possible to get the path using pure batch without resorting to PowerShell, VBS or Js but much more trickier

There are 2 keys in the registry containing path to special folders: `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders` and `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders`. Here's the way to parse them taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56454730/995714):

```bat
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set "StartupFolder="
for /F "skip=1 tokens=1,2*" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe QUERY "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /v Startup 2^>nul') do if /I "%%I" == "Startup" if not "%%~K" == "" if "%%J" == "REG_SZ" (set "StartupFolder=%%~K") else if "%%J" == "REG_EXPAND_SZ" call set "StartupFolder=%%~K"
if not defined StartupFolder for /F "skip=1 tokens=1,2*" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe QUERY "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders" /v Startup 2^>nul') do if /I "%%I" == "Startup" if not "%%~K" == "" if "%%J" == "REG_SZ" (set "StartupFolder=%%~K") else if "%%J" == "REG_EXPAND_SZ" call set "StartupFolder=%%~K"
if not defined StartupFolder set "StartupFolder=\"
if "%StartupFolder:~-1%" == "\" set "StartupFolder=%StartupFolder:~0,-1%"
if not defined StartupFolder set "StartupFolder=%UserProfile%\Startup"

echo Startup folder is: "%StartupFolder%"

endlocal
```