# %USERPROFILE%/Desktop no longer valid after relocating Desktop folder to OneDrive

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, environment-variables, special-folders

I've moved my Windows 10's `/Desktop` folder to a different location.

[image: Desktop properties]

As a result, my batch and Powershell scripts that were pointing to `%USERPROFILE%/Desktop` no longer worked. Is there another way to get the location of my desktop without hardcoding the new path in?

Comment: As a workaround for scripts that assume the default path (they shouldn't), you can create a bind mount (junction) or directory symlink at the default path that targets the configured path. If "D:\OneDrive\Desktop" is local (i.e. "D:" is a local drive), use a bind mount. If it's remote, use a directory symlink and ensure that local-to-remote (L2R) symlink evaluation is enabled for the system (it should be enabled by default).

Comment: `%USERPROFILE%/Desktop` was never correct although working usually. Correct would be `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop` for default configurations as the directory separator on Windows is ``\`` and not `/` as on Linux/Mac. See the Microsoft documentation about [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file) for details. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56454730/3074564) and try the batch code posted there from within a command prompt window to see if this batch file detects the correct directory for user's desktop on your Windows PC.

Comment: @Mofi Your referenced batch script works too!

Comment: @ErykSun That's pretty ingenious!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In PowerShell you can use [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getfolderpath?view=net-5.0)

```
[Environment]::GetFolderPath([Environment+SpecialFolder]::Desktop)
```

To use it from a batch file you can call powershell to get the path

```
powershell -C "[Environment]::GetFolderPath([Environment+SpecialFolder]::Desktop)"
```

and then save the result to a variable using [`for /f`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6359820/995714)

Comment: For batch scripts, you'd want to parse out the result into an environment variable using a `for /f` loop.