# Windows 10 Find Startup Folder in CMD

Tags: windows, cmd, autorun

I would like to find the location of the Autorun-Folder in Windows 10 via CMD.
I tried

```
dir /AD Startup
```

but I got following error:

```
Volume in drive C has no label.
Volume Serial Number is $here_is_the_serial_number
File Not Found
```

I know that there are other methods to find the Autorun-Folder but I need to find it via CMD.

Does any one know how I can find it?

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to search for a folder named `Startup` in all directories of a drive.

There are **by default** since Windows Vista:

- `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`
  This is the common startup folder in start menu for all users.
- `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`
  This is the startup folder in start menu of current user.

A batch file to get the really used **Startup** folder of current user is:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set "StartupFolder="
for /F "skip=1 tokens=1,2*" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe QUERY "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /v Startup 2^>nul') do if /I "%%I" == "Startup" if not "%%~K" == "" if "%%J" == "REG_SZ" (set "StartupFolder=%%~K") else if "%%J" == "REG_EXPAND_SZ" call set "StartupFolder=%%~K"
if not defined StartupFolder for /F "skip=1 tokens=1,2*" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe QUERY "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders" /v Startup 2^>nul') do if /I "%%I" == "Startup" if not "%%~K" == "" if "%%J" == "REG_SZ" (set "StartupFolder=%%~K") else if "%%J" == "REG_EXPAND_SZ" call set "StartupFolder=%%~K"
if not defined StartupFolder set "StartupFolder=\"
if "%StartupFolder:~-1%" == "\" set "StartupFolder=%StartupFolder:~0,-1%"
if not defined StartupFolder set "%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"

echo Startup folder of current user is:
echo "%StartupFolder%"

endlocal
```

For a full explanation of this code read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56454730/3074564) with same batch file code used to get the real **Desktop** folder of current user. I have just replaced all occurrences of `Desktop` by `Startup` to change the code for the **Startup** shell folder.

A batch file to get the really used **Common Startup** folder for all users is:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set "StartupFolder="
for /F "skip=1 tokens=2,3*" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe QUERY "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /v "Common Startup" 2^>nul') do if /I "%%I" == "Startup" if not "%%~K" == "" if "%%J" == "REG_SZ" (set "StartupFolder=%%~K") else if "%%J" == "REG_EXPAND_SZ" call set "StartupFolder=%%~K"
if not defined StartupFolder for /F "skip=1 tokens=2,3*" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe QUERY "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders" /v "Common Startup" 2^>nul') do if /I "%%I" == "Startup" if not "%%~K" == "" if "%%J" == "REG_SZ" (set "StartupFolder=%%~K") else if "%%J" == "REG_EXPAND_SZ" call set "StartupFolder=%%~K"
if not defined StartupFolder set "StartupFolder=\"
if "%StartupFolder:~-1%" == "\" set "StartupFolder=%StartupFolder:~0,-1%"
if not defined StartupFolder set "StartupFolder=%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"

echo Common startup folder for all users is:
echo "%StartupFolder%"

endlocal
```

The two **FOR** command lines could be also:

```
for /F "skip=1 tokens=1-3*" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe QUERY "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /v "Common Startup" 2^>nul') do if /I "%%I %%J" == "Common Startup" if not "%%~L" == "" if "%%K" == "REG_SZ" (set "StartupFolder=%%~L") else if "%%K" == "REG_EXPAND_SZ" call set "StartupFolder=%%~L"
if not defined StartupFolder for /F "skip=1 tokens=1-3*" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe QUERY "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders" /v "Common Startup" 2^>nul') do if /I "%%I %%J" == "Common Startup" if not "%%~L" == "" if "%%K" == "REG_SZ" (set "StartupFolder=%%~L") else if "%%K" == "REG_EXPAND_SZ" call set "StartupFolder=%%~L"
```

The two batch file solutions work also on Windows XP where the defaults cannot be used at all as the folder names are language dependent on Windows XP by default.

Searching for a shell folder on a drive is always the wrong approach to get the path of a shell folder. No Windows application written by Microsoft does that and so also no batch script should do that ever.

Answer (score -1):

Nvm. I got it. Following command works for me, if you who has same question:

```
dir Startup /s
```

Comment: No, it's `dir /A:D /S "%SystemDrive%\Startup"`…

Comment: The posted command line in the answer searches in current directory and its subdirectories for a directory entry – __file__ or __folder__ or __reparse point__ – with long or short name `Startup` not having the hidden attribute set. `/A-H` is the implicit default on not using option `/A`. So this command line is wrong as it may find also by chance a __file__ with name `Startup`.