# Recursive ffmpeg script preserving the subfolder structure

Tags: python, batch-file, recursion, ffmpeg, video-conversion

I've +300 videos in old format (.VOB) and I want to convert it in mp4. Luckly, after some documentation, I've managed to convert a couple of them, but I need to make it automatic. Don't know how, even which language should I use (python, batch...)

The thing is I want to preserve the subfolder structure. For example, if video 1 is inside folder B which is also inside folder A, the output must be in a folder named "output", and inside the converted video must be inside folder B and folder A

The ffmpeg command, if necessary:

```
ffmpeg -i input.vob -vf yadif=1 -c:v h264_nvenc output.mp4
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The task could be done with:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "BaseSourceFolder=C:\Temp\Source"
set "BaseTargetFolder=C:\Temp\Target"
for /R "%BaseSourceFolder%" %%I in (*.vob) do (
    set "FullSourceFileName=%%I"
    set "TargetFolder=%%~dpI"
    set "TargetFileName=%%~nI"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "TargetFolder=!TargetFolder:%BaseSourceFolder%=%BaseTargetFolder%!"
    if not exist "!TargetFolder!" md "!TargetFolder!"
    if exist "!TargetFolder!" "ffmpeg.exe" -i "!FullSourceFileName!" -vf yadif=1 -c:v h264_nvenc "!TargetFolder!!TargetFileName!.mp4"
    endlocal
)
endlocal
```

The folder paths of `BaseSourceFolder` and `BaseTargetFolder` must be defined in third and fourth line.

`BaseSourceFolder` cannot contain character `=` as otherwise the code would not work.

The two paths can be identical although in this case it would be more efficient to use a batch file with just one command line.

The executable file `ffmpeg.exe` should be specified in batch file with full path for more efficiency as in this case the Windows command processor `cmd.exe` would not need to search on each VOB file for the executable in current directory and if not found in one directory after the other listed in environment variable `PATH` until found.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `md /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38676582/3074564) for more details about the commands **SETLOCAL** and **ENDLOCAL**.