# Mux video files with mkvmerge in a batch with dynamic amount of files

Tags: windows, batch-file, video, mkv, matroska

Every time a .mkv file is needed to be muxed it comes with random amount of subtitles, and each subtitle is different language code.

So e.g.
Scenario 1:

```
video.mkv
eng.srt
fre.srt
ger.srt
```

Scenario 2:

```
video.mkv
rus.srt
spa.srt
```

The goal is to everytime running the same batch file make it pick it up amount of subtitles and mux it correctly with correct language codes, etc.

So far we got here:

```
        EnableDelayedExpansion

        for %%A in ("*.srt") do (
            set subtitle=%%~nA
        )

        for %%A in ("*.mkv") do (
        mkvmerge.exe -o "%%~nA.mkv" --default-track 0:yes "%%A"^
        --language 0:!subtitle! --default-track 0:no "!subtitle!.srt"^
        --language 0:!subtitle! --default-track 0:no "!subtitle!.srt"^
        --language 0:!subtitle! --default-track 0:no "!subtitle!.srt"^
        )
```

So far this is fixed amount of subtitles approach, not dynamic, so e.g. scenario 1. It almost works except it picks up every subtitle as last variable, so from scenario 1 each subtitle is muxed three times and named as `ger` for language and `ger.srt` used as source all three times because it's last one in the list by alphabet.

Goal: Each `!subtitle!` should be correct language and subtitle, as I understand by alphabet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have installed `mkvmerge.exe` and I don't have read the [documentation of mkvmerge](https://mkvtoolnix.download/doc/mkvmerge.html) and so don't know if the options provided in question are really correct.

The batch file below creates the command line with variable number of `--language` and `--default-track` options depending on `.srt` files found in current directory.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "SubtitleOptions="

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%I in (*.srt) do set "SubtitleOptions=!SubtitleOptions! --language 0:%%~nI --default-track 0:no "%%I""
endlocal & set "SubtitleOptions=%SubtitleOptions%"

for %%I in (*.mkv) do mkvmerge.exe -o "%%I" --default-track 0:yes "%%I"%SubtitleOptions%
endlocal
```

Please read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38676582/3074564) for details about the commands **SETLOCAL** and **ENDLOCAL** and [single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564) for an explanation of operator `&` used on command line with **ENDLOCAL** to set the variable `SubtitleOptions` in initial environment of the batch file with delayed expansion not enable to process correct also `.mkv` files with `!` in file name.

The string assigned to environment variable `SubtitleOptions` starts always with a space character if defined at all which is the reason why `%SubtitleOptions%` is directly after `"%%I"` on command line executing `mkvmerge.exe`.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`