# Windows batch loop variable starts with

Tags: batch-file

I have the following loop:

```
FOR %%a IN (%*) DO (

    IF "%%a"=="-D" (
        # Do something
    )
)
```

I want to check if `"%%a"` starts with `"-D"`, not equals.

I know about `%var:~0,2%` staff, but I don't see how to use it here.

**Update**

@Mofi's answer does solve the problem, but:

```
@echo off

SET JVM_ARGS=-server 

setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

FOR %%a IN (%*) DO (
     set "Argument=%%~a"
     setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion


    IF /I "!Argument:~0,2!"=="-D" (
        SET JVM_ARGS=%JVM_ARGS% %%a
    )
    endlocal
)

echo %JVM_ARGS%

endlocal
```

The problem I have is that `SET JVM_ARGS=%JVM_ARGS% %%a` doesn't work now, although it is executed. `echo %JVM_ARGS%` prints `-server` instead of `-server -Dxxx`

Comment: Copy `%%a` to a normal environment variable and do the sub-string expansion with that; regard that you will need [delayed variable expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) then!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
SET "JVM_ARGS=-server"
for %%I in (%*) do (
    set "Argument=%%~I"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    if /I "!Argument:~0,2!" == "-D" (
        rem echo Argument starting with -D is: !Argument!
        endlocal
        set "JVM_ARGS=%JVM_ARGS% %%I"
    ) else endlocal
)
rem set JVM_ARGS
endlocal
```

It works for:

- `-d`
- `-D`
- `"-d"`
- `"-D"`
- `-dhello`
- `-DHello`
- `-d"Hello world!"`
- `-D"!That's my function()!"`
- `"-dHello world!"`
- `"-DYes, argument processing is not trivial!"`

The above code is written for just **one** `-D` option. For multiple `-D` options it would be necessary to replace the line

```
        set "JVM_ARGS=%JVM_ARGS% %%I"
```

by

```
        set "Argument=%%I"
        call set "JVM_ARGS=%%JVM_ARGS%% %%Argument%%"
```

The command **CALL** results in parsing the command line being already

```
        call set "JVM_ARGS=%JVM_ARGS% %Argument%"
```

after parsing the entire command block before executing **FOR** a second time with replacing `%JVM_ARGS%` by current string value of this environment variable and `%Argument%` by the string value assigned to environment variable `Argument` above. The additional `Argument` environment variable is needed to avoid that a string after `-D` containing `%` is malformed as it would occur with using `%%I` instead of `%%Argument%%`.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `call /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `rem /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Please read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38676582/3074564) for details about the commands **SETLOCAL** and **ENDLOCAL**.

Answer (score 0):

This code solves the issues:

```
@echo off

SET JVM_ARGS=-server 

setlocal  EnableDelayedExpansion

FOR %%a IN (%*) DO (
echo %%a
    set "_arg_=%%~a"
    IF "!_arg_:~0,2!"=="-D" (
        SET "JVM_ARGS=!JVM_ARGS! %%a"
    )

)

echo %JVM_ARGS%

endlocal
```

Answer (score 0):

just to give you an alternative without delayed expansion:

```
FOR %%a IN (%*) DO (
    echo %%a|findstr /bc:"-D" >nul && (
        echo Do something
    )
)
```

which simply checks, if `%%a` starts with `-D` (instead of checking if the first two chars are `-D`), which gives the same results.

You may want to add findstr's `i` switch to make it case-insensitive (`findstr /bic:"-D"`)