# Batch to remove range of lines with start and stop delimiters from text file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I know batch isn't the best vehicle for this but my requirements dictate that I keep it.

I have text that looks like the following (it also has blank lines):

```
Line AAA text

Line BBB text
! ***@@@ START
Body text here
! ***@@@ END
Line XXX
Line YYY
!Comment Line etc
```

I want to remove the ! ***@@@ START and END lines and everything in between and then save over the original file.

I found and modified the code below but it strips out my blank lines and the ! characters.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "sourceFile=c:\temp\startfile.txt"
set "tempFile=c:\temp\tempfile.txt"
set "StartPhrase=! ***@@@ START"
set "EndPhrase=! ***@@@ END"
set /a lineNum=0

REM check file for search phrase, store line as refLine
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN (%sourceFile%) DO (
    set /a lineNum+=1
    echo !lineNum! = "%%i"
    if "%%i" == "%StartPhrase%" (
        echo Found "%StartPhrase%" on line !lineNum!
        set /a StartrefLine=!lineNum!
    )
        if "%%i" == "%EndPhrase%" (
        echo Found "%EndPhrase%" on line !lineNum!
        set /a EndrefLine=!lineNum!
    )
)

REM make backup
copy "%sourceFile%" "%sourceFile%-%DATE:/=-% %TIME::=-%.txt"

echo. 2>%tempFile%

REM Rewrite file 
set /a lineNum=0
    set /a lowEnd=%StartrefLine%
    echo "Set low end to %lowEnd%"
    set /a highEnd=%EndrefLine%
    echo "Set high end to %highEnd%"
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN (%sourceFile%) DO (
    set /a lineNum+=1
    if !lineNum! GTR %lowEnd% (
        if !lineNum! LSS %highEnd% (
           echo "Skipping line #!lineNum!"
        )
    )
    if !lineNum! LSS %lowEnd% (
        echo "Writing Line !lineNum! %%i to temp file..."
        echo %%i >> %tempFile%
    )

    if !lineNum! GTR %highEnd% (
        echo "Writing Line !lineNum! %%i to temp file..."
        echo %%i >> %tempFile%
    )
)

REM get target filename only 
for %%F in ("%sourceFile%") do set fname=%%~nxF
REM del original file and rename tempfile
echo "Deleting original file..."
echo Y | del "%sourceFile%"
echo "Renaming %tempFile% to %fname%"
ren "%tempFile%" "%fname%"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible and quite simple way is to let the particular line markers toggle a flag that indicates whether or not the currently iterated line is to be output:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_FILE=C:\TEMP\startfile.txt"
set "_TMPF=%TEMP%\%~n0_%RANDOM%.tmp"
set "_START=! ***@@@ START"
set "_END=! ***@@@ END"

rem // Initialise flag:
set "FLAG=#"
rem // Write to temporary file:
> "%_TMPF%" (
    rem /* Loop through lines of input file; `findstr` precedes each line with
    rem    line number plus `:`, so they do not appear empty to `for /F`: */
    for /F "delims=" %%L in ('findstr /N "^" "%_FILE%"') do (
        rem // Store current line string (with line number prefix) to variable:
        set "LINE=%%L"
        rem // Toggle delayed expansion to avoid loss of `!`:
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        rem // Remove line number prefix to retrieve original line string:
        set "LINE=!LINE:*:=!"
        rem // Check contents of current line:
        if "!LINE!"=="!_START!" (
            endlocal & set "FLAG="
        ) else if "!LINE!"=="!_END!" (
            endlocal & set "FLAG=#"
        ) else (
            rem // Check state of flag for outputting:
            if defined FLAG echo(!LINE!
            endlocal
        )
    )
) && (
    rem // Move temporary file onto target file:
    move /Y "%_TMPF%" "%_FILE%"
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

Answer (score 0):

This task could be done with the worst script interpreter available for this task with following code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "SourceFile=C:\Temp\startfile.txt"
if not exist "%SourceFile%" exit /B
set "TempFile=%SourceFile%.tmp"
set "PrintLines=1"

(for /F "delims=" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /N /R "^" "%SourceFile%"') do (
    set "Line=%%I"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    if defined PrintLines (
        if not "!Line: ***@@@ START=!" == "!Line!" (
            endlocal
            set "PrintLines="
        ) else (
            echo(!Line:*:=!
            endlocal
        )
    ) else (
        if not "!Line: ***@@@ END=!" == "!Line!" (
            endlocal
            set "PrintLines=1"
        ) else endlocal
    )
))>"%TempFile%"

move /Y "%TempFile%" "%SourceFile%"
if exist "%TempFile%" del "%TempFile%"
endlocal
```

`for /F` results in ignoring all empty lines. For that reason command `findstr` is used to output all lines with line number and colon at beginning in a separate command process started with `%ComSpec% /c` in background. So there is no empty line anymore in captured output of `findstr`.

Each captured line starting with a digit in range `1` to `9` is assigned completely to the loop variable `I` because of using option `delims=` to define an empty list of string delimiters to disable the default line splitting behavior on normal spaces and horizontal tabs.

The line with line number and colon at beginning is assigned to the environment variable `Line` while delayed environment variable expansion is disabled. This is important as otherwise the Windows command processor `cmd.exe` processing the batch file would [parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/) the command line `set "Line=%%I"` after having replaced `%%I` by current line with enabled [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) and would interpret each `!` as beginning/end of a delayed expanded environment variable.

Then the delayed expansion is enabled for further processing the line depending on printing lines currently enabled as by default until a line is found containing the string  `***@@@ START`. Next the environment variable `PrintLines` is undefined until a line is found containing the string  `***@@@ END` on which `PrintLines` is defined again for the following lines.

Please read second half of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38676582/3074564) for details about the commands **SETLOCAL** and **ENDLOCAL**.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `del /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `exit /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `move /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Comment: I absolutely love the introductory sentence! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q65218525.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"

SET "blockstart=! ***@@@ START"
SET "blockend=! ***@@@ END"

SET "repro=Y"

(

FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a IN ('findstr /n /r ".*" "%filename1%"') DO (
 IF /i "%%b"=="%blockstart%" SET "repro=" 
 IF /i "%%b"=="%blockend%" (SET "repro=Y") ELSE (IF DEFINED repro IF "%%b"=="" (ECHO.) ELSE (ECHO %%b))
)
)>"%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances. The listing uses a setting that suits my system.

I used a file named `q65218525.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Produces the file defined as `%outfile%`

Since your code saves the original file under a new name and creates a new file with the old name but your requirement seems to be to simply overwrite the old file, I'll leave that part as an exercise.

First, define the strings involved, and a flag (which I've called `repro`) which is initialised to reproduce the data.

Then use `findstr` with the `/N` option to prefix each line, including blank lines, with *number*: which is then parsed by the `for/r` to put the number in `%%a` and the text in `%%b`.

Check `%%b` for the target strings and frob the `repro` flag as appropriate to select whether to reproduce the line read or not.

Comment: I thought also about this simple solution, but it has the disadvantage that all `:` at beginning of a line in the text file are removed by __FOR__ because of `delims=:`. The example file contents in question does not contain a line with one or more `:` at beginning of the line, but that is most likely just because of questioner not knowing that this is another special use case on processing the lines of the text file.

Comment: @Mofi - yes, I should have mentioned that. Should be fine if no data lines start `:` though.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this would be using PowerShell. Invoke it from the command line or a .bat file script using:

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -File '.\Slice-File.ps1'
```

=== Slice-File.ps1

```
$SourceFile = 'C:\src\t\Slice-File.txt'
$TempFile = New-TemporaryFile

$WriteIt = $true
Get-Content -Path '.\Slice-File.txt' |
    ForEach-Object {
        if ($_ -eq '! ***@@@ START') { $WriteIt = $false }
        if ($WriteIt) { $_ }
        if ($_ -eq '! ***@@@ END') { $WriteIt = $true }
    } |
    Out-File -FilePath $TempFile -Encoding ascii

Remove-Item -Path $SourceFile
Move-Item -Path $TempFile -Destination $SourceFile
```